# Java: Instantiating a generic class with no default constructor

Tags: java, generics, instantiation, default-constructor

I am trying to do this:

```
public class BaseTable<T extends TableEntry>

{

    protected int mRows;
    protected int mCols;
    protected ArrayList<T> mEntries;

    public BaseTable(int rows, int cols)
    {
        mRows = rows;
        mCols = cols;
        mEntries = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            mEntries.add(new T(cols)); //this obv. doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiating generics is hard enough as it is, but what makes this even harder is that `T` here does not have a default constructor, it takes a single `int` parameter in its constructor.

How can this be done?

---

I have asked a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107034/java-classt-and-class-difference-when-used-from-within-outside-of-the-class) here too. I'd be grateful if you could answer that as well.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java) is related, but only is relevant where the classes are assumed to have a default constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was already said, that you can't create an instance of T with `new`, so
I would use the Factory Pattern or a Prototype Pattern

So your constructor would look like
`public BaseTable(int rows, int cols, LineFactory factory)` with an appropriate instance of a factory.

In your case, I would prefer the Prototype Pattern, because your TableEntry objects are probably very light-weight. Your code would look like:

```
public BaseTable(int rows, int cols, T prototype)
{       
  mRows = rows;
  mCols = cols;
  prototype.setColumns(cols);
  mEntries = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T newClone = (T)prototype.clone();
    mEntries.add(newClone); //this obv. does work :)
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  new BaseTable<SimpleTableEntry>(10, 2, new SimpleTableEntry());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The good reason why it *shouldn't* be done like this is, that you can't force a sub class to implement a certain constructor. It's very obvious for implementations of interface, for they don't include a contract for constructors.

And if your real or abstract class `BaseTable` had a constructor `BaseTable(int columns)`, the fictious sub class `VectorTable` with a single column wouldn't need to implement it and could do something bad like

```
public VectorTable(int intialValue) {
  super(1);
  this.initialValue = initialValue;
}
```

So first, you don't know if `T` implements the constructor at all and second, you don't know if the constructor has the same purpose (*which it really should have in proper code!!*)

So I think, a better solution is to move the parametrized part from the constructor into a separate (final?) method, create the instance with the default constructor and call that initialization method right afterwards.

You may think of implementing a `BaseTableFactory` if you want to make sure, that all BaseTable sub classes are always initialized correctly.

**Edit**

And `new T()` (instantiating the default constructor) isn't possible as well, because no class can be *forced* to implement an accessible default constructor. I still think, the factory pattern is your best friend here.

Comment: **And**, `T` can be an abstract class or interface.  In which case, it could not be instantiated *directly* under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Factory interface:

```
public interface TableEntryFactory<T extends TableEntry>{
 public T create (int cols);
}
```

also you need to make a factory for each class "with type T":

```
// for every class of type T
public class SpecialTableEntry extends TableEntry{
   SpecialTableEntry(int cols){
      ...
   }
}

// make a factory creating instance of this class
public class SpecialTableEntryFactory implements TableEntryFactory<SpecialTableEntry> {
   @Override
   public SpecialTableEntry create (int cols){
       return new SpecialTableEntry(cols);
   }
}
```

Your code will look like:

```
public class BaseTable<T extends TableEntry>

{

protected int mRows;
protected int mCols;
protected ArrayList<T> mEntries;

public BaseTable(int rows, int cols, TableEntryFactory<T> tableFactory)
{
    mRows = rows;
    mCols = cols;
    mEntries = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
        mEntries.add(tableFactory.create(cols)); //this should work now
      }
  }
}
```

You can call it like:

```
TableEntryFactory<SpecificTableEntry> myFactory = new SpecificTableEntryFactory();
BaseTable<?> table = new BaseTable<SpecificTableEntry>(rows,cols,myFactory);
```

P.S. It's not my original solution. I have found it somewhere long time ago and used it in my code. Unfortunately I can't find a link to an original idea...

Answer (score -1):

Simple!

Use a static factory method instead of a constructor:

```
public static <T extends TableEntry> newInstance(int rows, int cols) {
    return new BaseTable<T>(rows, cols);
}
```

To instantiate type

```
BaseTable<Number> = BaseTable.newInstance(10, 20);
```