# Java generics - get class?

Tags: java, generics

I got a list, programmed like this: `public class MyList<T>`. Is there any way to use the T variable to get the name of class (so I can, from within `MyList`, know if T is String, Socket, etc.)?

EDIT: Nevermind, found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java#Generics

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**Short answer**: You can't.

**Long answer**:

Due to the way generics is implemented in Java, the generic type T is not kept at runtime. Still, you can use a private data member:

```
public class Foo<T> 
{
    private Class<T> type;

    public Foo(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; } 
}
```

Usage example:

```
Foo<Integer> test = new Foo<Integer>(Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 75):

I like the solution from

http://www.nautsch.net/2008/10/28/class-von-type-parameter-java-generics/

```
public class Dada<T> {

    private Class<T> typeOfT;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Dada() {
        this.typeOfT = (Class<T>)
                ((ParameterizedType)getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
...
```

Comment: This solution works fine for me. Advantage is no need to pass additional parameters like other solutions mentioned. Any issues when using this?

Comment: it's still working fine

Comment: This will only work if the runtime class is a direct subclass of the generic superclass.

Comment: Will this cause a significant performance penalty from the reflection?

Comment: This **DOESN'T** work with dynamic proxies so popular in modern frameworks.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Answer (score 28):

You are seeing the result of [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). From that page...

> When a generic type is instantiated,
>   the compiler translates those types by
>   a technique called type erasure — a
>   process where the compiler removes all
>   information related to type parameters
>   and type arguments within a class or
>   method. Type erasure enables Java
>   applications that use generics to
>   maintain binary compatibility with
>   Java libraries and applications that
>   were created before generics.
>
> For instance, Box<String> is
>   translated to type Box, which is
>   called the raw type — a raw type is a
>   generic class or interface name
>   without any type arguments. **This means
>   that you can't find out what type of
>   Object a generic class is using at
>   runtime.**

This also looks like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t) which has a [pretty good answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t/3437930#3437930).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure if this works in all cases (needs at least Java 1.5):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main 
{
    public class A
    {   
    }

    public class B extends A
    {       
    }


    public Map<A, B> map = new HashMap<Main.A, Main.B>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        try
        {
            Field field = Main.class.getField("map");           
            System.out.println("Field " + field.getName() + " is of type " + field.getType().getSimpleName());

            Type genericType = field.getGenericType();

            if(genericType instanceof ParameterizedType)
            {
                ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) genericType;               
                Type[] typeArguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();

                for(Type typeArgument : typeArguments) 
                {   
                    Class<?> classType = ((Class<?>)typeArgument);                  
                    System.out.println("Field " + field.getName() + " has a parameterized type of " + classType.getSimpleName());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

This will output:

> Field map is of type Map
>   Field map has a parameterized type of A
>   Field map has a parameterized type of B

Comment: Once I tried to do similar during refactoring of General DAO, so I went through some similar code samples. Don't remember why, but I decided not to go with such approach (I think it didn't work well in all cases, maybe class hierarchy was mandatory). Your example does work :) +1 P.S. Some extended tutorial I've found: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Comment: I found the original article where I lifted this from (the example above is extracted from one of our work-projects): http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html#fieldtypes  The article says this only works with public-fields, but that's not true, you can access protected and private fields via reflection too (just use getDeclaredField instead of getField)

Comment: This does not answer the question. This gets the type used in declaring a field. How is this relevant?

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to get the Class of the generic type this way:

```
class MyList<T> {
  Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) DAOUtil.getTypeArguments(MyList.class, this.getClass()).get(0);
}
```

You need two functions from this file: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/source/browse/trunk/dao/src/main/java/com/googlecode/genericdao/dao/DAOUtil.java

For more explanation: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Comment: Here, MyList.class and this.getClass() both are same value!!

Comment: Yes, you can. This works:  public String getParameterTypeName() {
  return ((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0])
    .getTypeName();
 }

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5335039/Get-generic-type-name-in-java