# what is Generic . and how to make possible to get the generic type on runtime

Tags: java, generics

How can you determine what type of object a generic is using at runtime ?

Comment: Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837190/java-generics-get-class

Comment: Simple answer: you cannot know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we explain **What is Generic**

Generic in Java is one of important feature added in **Java 5**,

From [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type
>   checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To
>   implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>     Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode,
>     therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
>
> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized
>   types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

Now how to make possible to get the generic type on runtime, with the help of this link

read: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Nov/11/Dynamically-creating-a-Generic-Type-at-Runtime

Answer (score 3):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you cannot determine the actual type parameter(s) of a generic object instance. The best you can do is set things up so you can pass a class object to code that needs to know the actual type. For example, this is what [`java.util.EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) does in one of its constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the `T` in `List<T>` (for instance), you can't, because Java uses [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At *runtime*, a `List<T>` just looks like a `List`. This is true except in the edge case of anonymous classes, where it's possible if you [jump through hoops](http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Using_TypeTokens_to_retrieve_generic_parameters) to find the parameter type. But in the general case, you cannot. You usually have to communicate that information separately.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the object type of "Generics" at run time. If we use object.getclass(), so we can get object of any class with the class name.