# How to Cast the Class Object of a Generic Type to a Specific Instance of that Type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a generic interface, lets call it `GenericInterface<T>`. I need to pass the *class object* of that interface to a method that expects (specified through another type parameter) a specific instance of that type. Let's assume I want to call `java.util.Collections.checkedList()`:

```
List<GenericInterface<Integer>> list = Collections.checkedList(
    new ArrayList<GenericInterface<Integer>>(),
    GenericInterface.class);
```

This does not work because `Class<GenericInterface>` cannot be implicitly casted to `Class<GenericInterface<Integer>>`, what is the most type safe way to do that? The best I could come up is this:

```
List<GenericInterface<Integer>> list = Collections.checkedList(
    new ArrayList<GenericInterface<Integer>>(),
    (Class<GenericInterface<Integer>>) (Class<?>) GenericInterface.class);
```

It works but won't protect me from e.g. changing the list's type to `List<SomeOtherInterface>` without also replacing the class object parameter with `SomeOtherInterface.class`.

Comment: I know that in this example, the checked list will not actually check the type parameter `T` of the `GenericInterface` instances added to the list, this is not what I'm after. I just want the call to `checkedList()` to be more type-safe, if possible.

Comment: This is the best you can do

Comment: This is a perfect example of where you could just do the unchecked cast and suppress it.  You're controlling creation of the delegate list, so there's nothing to be concerned about.  But Java just can't let you go and do it without complaining, because for all it knows, the cast could allow a type error.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Class Object'? Not a Java term I recognize.

Comment: @user207421 Look at the first example in the question: `GenericInterface.class` is the _class object_ of the interface `GenericInterface`. Class objects are instances of class [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). An example where these are used is when instantiating an array with an element type chosen at runtime using [`Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-).

Answer (score -1):

There are similar questions:

- [Java generics - get class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837190/java-generics-get-class)
- [How do I get a class instance of generic type T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t), from which I quote:

> The short answer is, that there is no way to find out the runtime type
> of generic type parameters in Java.

Comment: This does not address my question. It would maybe be in the interest of the implementor of `checkedList()`, but I only need to pass an instance of `Class` with the correct non-generic type to a parameter with a generic type.

Comment: in that case remove generic type of the class `List<GenericInterface> list = Collections.checkedList(
    new ArrayList<GenericInterface>(),
    GenericInterface.class);`

Comment: But that's less type safe than what I started with! In my second example, _only_ the second argument of the call to `checkedList()` is not type safe.