# How wrap a generic class in java

Tags: java, generics

If I am writing a wrapper for a generic class, which I have tried to embed the type into at construction (as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837190/java-generics-get-class)):

```
class Foo<T> {
    private T value;
    private Class<T> type;

    public Foo(Class<T> type, T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

I have a list of instances of `Foo`, which I want to transform into a list of `FooWrapper`s, along these lines:

```
List<Foo<?>> someListOfFoos = ...
List<FooWrapper<?>> fooWrappers = someListOfFoos
    .stream()
    .map(foo -> FooWrapper.from(foo))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any way to recover the type of each element in `someListOfFoos` when building each `FooWrapper`? Something along these lines:

```
class FooWrapper<T> {
    private Foo<T> foo;

    public static FooWrapper<?> from(Foo<?> toWrap) {
        Class<E> type = toWrap.getType(); // i know this is wrong
        return new FooWrapper<type>(toWrap); // this is very wrong
    }

    private FooWrapper(Foo<T> foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using raw types for `someListOfFoos` and `fooWrappers`?

Comment: @Tom, I want the list to contain `Foo`s of any type.

Comment: Then at least use a wildcard.

Comment: OK. Updated question.

Comment: See this answer about typesafe heterogenous containers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/416611/2513200 - basically, you can only recover the type if you know it and can cast to it.

Comment: What do you gain by correctly inferring the type, only to immediately throw it away when adding it to the list?

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk - good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to modify your `FooWrapper#from` slightly, by introducing a generic:

```
public static <E> FooWrapper<E> from(Foo<E> toWrap) {
    return new FooWrapper<E>(toWrap);
}
```