# Java generic method type casting

Tags: java, generics

Why this happened? One line in the code works well while the other similar line doesn't. Does the automatic type cast only happen in certain conditions? I have tried to assign gt.echoV() to an Object and it works well; but when I assign it to a String, the same error will come out again.

```
public class GeneMethodTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        GeneMethodTest gt = new GeneMethodTest();
        gt.<String>echoV(); //this line works well
        gt.<String>echoV().getClass();//this line leads to a type cast exception                                                          
    }

    public <T> T echoV() {
        T t=(T)(new Object());                                                                    
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/3437930/1316346

Comment: `(T)(new Object())` is an *unchecked cast* - make sure to read up on what that is and its implications, along with *type erasure*.

Comment: Yup, i know that. @PaulBellora Actually (T)(new Object()) will do nothing during run time because of type erasure. The problem is when I call gt.<String>.echoV() the automatic class casting doesn't take effect while it does take effects when i call gt.<Stirng>echo.getClass()

Comment: @PaulBellora care to explain your comment a bit further ? from the documentation: "Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds **or Object** if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods."
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: @charles_ma That's because the `<String>` in of itself has nothing to do with casting - it's just the type argument to the generic method. `gt.<String>echoV()` alone requires no cast to be inserted by the compiler, so that doesn't fail at runtime.

Comment: @PaulBellora yup i think maybe this is the reason. I think the compiler won't bother inserting code if you don't use the resulting reference. But when I execute Object o = gt.<String>echoV(); it works well too, so the compiler must have done some extra work to tell whether it is necessary to do the casting~

Comment: @alfasin I'm not sure I understand your comment. I was recommending the OP (and others) read up on the concepts of type erasure and unchecked casts.

Comment: @PaulBellora I wrote that comment cause you said that the problem lies within `(T)(new Object())` but I think that the problem is not with this casting (inside the method) - but with the cast of the returned object - the line that Charles marked in his question. But maybe I'm missing something and that's why I asked you to further explain your comment.

Comment: The problem, of course, is that echoV is returning an Object, not a String.  In the case where the return value from echoV is not used, javac does not generate a cast to String.  But any attempt to reference the value generates the cast and hence the error.

Comment: (Remember, ALL that generic types do is cause the compiler to insert cast operations -- nothing in the logic is changed except for the added casts, and, in particular, an Object will not magically be turned into a String.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gt.<String>echoV().getClass();` produces the equivalent of the following sequence of operations:

```
// Inside echoV
Object t = new Object();  // Note that this is NOT a String!
Object returnValue = t;
// In main
String stackTemp = (String) returnValue;  // This is the operation that fails
stackTemp.getClass();
```

What you get "for free" with generics is that `(String)` cast.  Nothing else.

Comment: That's right. It seems the compiler will figure out when to insert code rather than insert it every single time~

Comment: @charles_ma - Yep, take away the getClass and the compiler figures there's no need for the cast.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfect, nothing special, normal use of generics

```
gt.<String>echoV(); //this line works well
```

Here do we have something less obvious. Because generic method are defined at runtime does the jvm not know what kind of Class the generic method will return at compiletime, hence the classTypeException

```
gt.<String>echoV().getClass();//this line leads to a type cast exception
```

you should allocated it to a variable first, because the jvm does know the type of the variable at compiletime

```
String s = gt.<String>echoV();
s.getClass();
```

Comment: Actually if you do `System.out.println(gt.<String>echoV())` you got a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Comment: same problem, System.out.println expects a string as parameter. If this is not the case, it will call the toString() of the object, but at compileat does the jvm not know from what object

Comment: I believe maybe it's because in the first line, i called the function but didn't use the reference so the compiler didn't bother adding any class cast code; but in the second line, i tried to use the resulting reference from the call so the compiler had to insert class casting code there~ And same situation when you call System.out.println(gt.<String>echoV()) @System.exit

Comment: @user1394628 every object has a `toString()` method hence it doesn't have anything to do with things that happened during compile-time.

Comment: @user1394628 I believe String s = gt.<String>echoV(); will produce a class cast exception at runtime too~

Comment: But the compiler doesn't *have to* assign it to a temporary variable of type `String`. Since `.getClass()` is a method on `Object`, it *could* just assign it to a temporary variable of type `Object`, and thus not need a cast.

Comment: `String s = gt.<String>echoV();` will fail too.

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
gt.<String>echoV().getClass();
```

to:

```
(gt.echoV()).getClass();
```

and it'll compile 
(it'll return: class `java.lang.Object`)

The root of the `ClassCastException` is that the method returns `t` (of generic type `T` which is an object) and you try to downcast it to a String. You can also change your code to return:

```
return (T)"some-string";
```

in order to remove the error.

Generic are used by the compiler to check what type of object to expect, so it can catch mistakes the developer made in compile time (vs. run-time errors). So IMHO this way of using generics beats the purpose.

Comment: downvoter - care to write a comment ? did I write something inaccurate ?

Comment: I think the question is about the use of Generics, not the ´getClass()´ itself method.

Comment: @System.exit I think that my answer covers that as well.

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing that you made some modifications :). I think I judged your answer too early, but yes, now your answer covers the question.