# cannot find method in generic class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a function that takes in a generic `Class`, does some work with a function of that `Class`, then return an instance of said `Class`.

I'm getting a compiler error: `error: cannot select from a type variable - [ERROR] T.getManagers(), T.class);`. Here is the function:

```
public static <T extends Bar> T getFoo(Class<T> fooClass , String person)
{
    T foo = null;
    try
    {
        Configuration config = Configuration.getConfiguration(person);
        foo = (T) Bar.getInstance(config,T.getManagers(), T.class);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
    return foo;
}
```

EDIT: Is there a way I can get around calling `Bar.getManagers()`? What I'm trying to do with generics is that I have say 5 classes very similar to Bar but not exactly the same. They all have `getManagers()`. By using a generic like `T.getManagers()` I'm trying to get around calling the explicit names in the code and using a generic one instead.

Comment: `getManagers()` is method of `Bar` class?

Comment: You cannot call a static on a generic.  There is no way to ensure that every implementation of Bar implements a static getManagers() method.

Comment: Yes, it's a public static method.

Comment: The `T.getManagers()` should probably be `Bar.getManager()`. And `T.class` should probably be `fooClass`. But you might have to post your `Bar` class and the `getInstance` method for more focussed help.

Comment: Please post the code of `Bar`, and in particular `getInstance()`. I definitely agree with @Marco13, we can't really help you with what you currently provided.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use constructs that are not allowed in Java:

- You can't use `T.getManagers()`, because it is a static method, and the class `T` won't be available at runtime (type erasure). If the `getManagers()` method exists in class `Bar` (and it should*), then use `Bar.getManagers()` instead.
- You can't use `T.class` for the same reason, the class `T` won't be available at runtime. Use `fooClass` instead.

The code you provided should look like:

```
public static <T extends Bar> T getFoo(Class<T> fooClass , String person) {
    T foo = null;
    try {
        Configuration config = Configuration.getConfiguration(person);
        foo = (T) Bar.getInstance(config, Bar.getManagers(), fooClass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
    return foo;
}
```

(*) This method should be in `Bar` because it seems to be a common behaviour that you use here, and that you seem to expect from all `T`s that could extend `Bar`. There is no such thing as inheritance for static methods.

Comment: I tried to use fooClass in place of T and got this error: `error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] fooClass.getManagers(), fooClass.class);`.

Comment: Try `fooClass`, not `fooClass.class`

Comment: `fooClass.getManagers()` is forbidden. You should use `Bar` instead, as I stated in my answer.

Comment: I can't use Bar, the point of the method is there are 4 other classes I need to call and I'm trying to do it with a generic. So if I always call `Bar` then when I need to get a manager for `XYZ` I'm still calling `Bar`'s getManagers(), not XYZ's.

Comment: You can't use static methods this way. Use instance methods instead, then you'll be able to use inheritance. I think you're misusing generics here, I don't understand what you're trying to do. It's hard to give design advice without more info on your use case. Please provide your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

`T.class` is prohibited construction, you cannot use it because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Please take a look on a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t/3437930#3437930)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection on the `fooClass` object to obtain and execute the `getManagers()` method.  It will fail at runtime if the class doesn't have the method though.

```
public static <T extends Bar> T getFoo(Class<T> fooClass , String person)
{
    T foo = null;
    try
    {
        Configuration config = Configuration.getConfiguration(person);
        Method getManagers = fooClass.getDeclaredMethod("getManagers");
        foo = (T) Bar.getInstance(config, getManagers.invoke(null), T.class);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
    return foo;
}
```

This is not a great practice, but should work.