# How to return a class object "type" in java generics?

Tags: java, class, generics, types, return

Imagine to have a java class

```
public class FixedClassOfStrings {

  List<String> myMember=new ArrayList<String>();

  // omissed all non relevant code...

  public Class getMyType() {
    return String.class;
  }
}
```

How can I make it paramteric, by using java generics?

My attempts fail:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

  List<T> myMember=new ArrayList<T>();

  public Class getMyType() {
    return T.class; // this gives "Illegal class literal for the type parameter T"
  }
}
```

Also, how can I avoid warning: "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized" in the FixedClassOsStrings? is it ok to declare:

```
  public Class<String> getMyType() {
    return String.class;
  }
  ...
```

And if it is ok, what shall I return using generics?

```
  public Class<T> getMyType() {
    return T.class; // this gives "Illegal class literal for the type parameter T"
  }
  ...
```

All hints will be appreciated!!!

Comment: `T.class` is a compile-time constant, I think, but because the code is generic the compiler can't determine what class object to return.

Comment: Very similar to the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like this:

```
public Class<T> getMyType() {
    return /* some instance of T */.getClass();
}
```

Alternatively, an easy solution is passing the instance upon construction:

```
public class YourClass<T> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    public YourClass (/* arguments */, Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is not type safe. "Some instance of T" could be `null` or its class could be a subclass of T.

Comment: Also, `/* some instance of T */.getClass()` has type `Class<? extends T>`, not `Class<T>`