# Class instance of generics type T BUT which extends a super class with generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I've use [this method](http://www.nautsch.net/2008/10/28/class-von-type-parameter-java-generics/) to retrieve the type of my generic, and no problem... **until now**
Now, I've got this kind of structure:

```
public class Toto<T> extends OtherOne<X,Y,Z> {...}`
```

and when I use the

```
((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];`
```

it's return me the type `Class<X>` of my OtherOne class, not `Class<T>`!

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? Whatever I've tried didn't work, and I don't want to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437930/244911) of getting the class as an argument of my Constructor.

Answer (score -1):

In order to learn what `T` is it will have to be captured in a subclass. Ex:

```
public class StringToto extends Toto<String> {}
Class<?> t = (Class<?>)((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

This is the case since types are only retrievable at runtime if they're part of a type definition.

Comment: it isn't what I ask, please read again : public class Toto<T> extends OtherOne<X,Y,Z> {...}. I got a generic class wich extends an other generic class

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - are you trying to get the value of `T`?

Comment: Yes I need to get the Class of T, but on a class wich extends a class which have generics too, so the common ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]; doesnt work !

Comment: If you want to get `T`, the actual value of T (such as String) must be captured in a type definition, such as in the example I posted. Without being captured in a type definition, the value of `T` is erased at runtime.