# Find Type of List<?>

Tags: java, android, reflection, gson

I have a:

```
TypeToken<T> type;
```

where

```
type is List<?>;
```

What I want is get the Object.class that the List is refering, I don`t need to know the Class, I only need it to pass to a constructor like:

```
new GsonListDeserializerPrizer(clazz)

clazz came from List<?> - List<clazz>
```

I know that s a little complicated to understand my question, but I've tried a lots of solutions and none worked.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible at all. The problem is that at the runtime, there is no such thing as a `List<clazz>`, it is just a `List`.

Comment: you can get an element of the list and call getclass on it

Comment: @SolomonPByer I could do that, but the problem is that my model is a List<?> but the server can return List<?> or an object. I found that: ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type.getType(); Class<?> clazz = (Class) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; that might work I'll try it and post here if worked

Comment: you can still getclass to see if its a list see if its holding anything get one of the things its holding and getclass on that you may need to use some code to check all the elements in the list to see if there is a super class or subclass or whatever.

Comment: @SolomonPByer Seems like a correct comment, but hardly readable. You may require some dots and comma's & general interpunction.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: comment with grammar:you can still use getclass() to see if its a list,then if it is see if its holding anything,then if it is  get one of the things its holding and use getclass() on that.(You may need to use some code to check all the elements in the list to see if there is a super class or subclass or whatever.)