# Checking Class Passed to Parameterized Function

Tags: java, generics, instanceof, parameterized

Is there a way to check what class you passed to a parameterized function using something like instanceof? In some ways this kind of defeats the purpose (I get that), but I was wondering if something like this was possible.

```
public static <T> List<T> foo(String parseMe) {
    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<T>();
    if (T instanceof Type1) {
        ...
    } else if (T instanceof Type2) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: No, as Java's impl of generics is based on type-erasure. See answer and solution to your problem in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: No, see [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).