# How can I obtain the class type from a generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have a list of class types T and the following method that is called for the the class types:

```
<T extends PersistentEntity> void subscribe(Class<T> clazz, HBaseStreamFactory factory) {
    final DisposablePublisher<Tuple.Tuple2<T,T>> publisher 
        = new DisposablePublisher<>(factory.createPublisher(?));
}
```

The method createPublisher() should receive the class type of Tuple.Tuple2< T,T> instead of ?, how can I obtain it from knowing the clazz?

Comment: You can't. `T` gets erased when compiling. This is called [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: you can get Tuple.Tuple2 type via Tuple.Tuple2.class . You cannot get the type of T because of type erasure.

Comment: You can pass the type explicitly to the method `createPublisher`, can't you? In this way the the signature of the method will become the following: `createPublisher(Class<T> clazz)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get class instance of generics type T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tuple.Tuple2.class`, which is the class object representing the `Tuple.Tuple2` class at runtime. (There are no generics at runtime anyway. There is just one class object for each class.) This expression has type `Class<Tuple.Tuple2>`. If you really want something of type `Class<Tuple.Tuple<T,T>>` to satisfy the compiler, you can do some unsafe casts:

```
factory.createPublisher((Class<Tuple.Tuple<T,T>>)(Class<?>)Tuple.Tuple2.class)
```

(or you can cast the result of `createPublisher()` accordingly; I don't have the method signatures so I can't predict how that would be written)