# how to get the persistent class parameter of a class generic? <T>

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired

here's my code:

AbstractClass

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T>{

    public abstract Class<?> getPersistentClass();

    public void invokeNothing(){
        Class<T> c = getPersistentClass();
        // do something....
        // some code...
    }

}
```

CommonClass

```
public class CommonClass<T> extends AbstractClass<T>{

    public Class<?> getPersistentClass(){
        // how to get the persistent class of generic T
        // T.class
        return // T.class
    }

}
```

Service

```
public class CommonService{

    @Autowired
    private CommonAbstractClass<Person> commonClass;

    public void invoke(){
        commonClass.invokeNothing();
    }


}
```

how to get the persistent class parameter of a class generic?  in my class CommonClass in method getPersistentClass();

please help me thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way (at least no easy way I am aware of except reflection in some cases) to get the runtime type of the generic type parameter due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You can use the following safe work-around:

```
public class CommonClass<T>{

    private final Class<T> type;

    public CommonClass(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<T> getMyType() {
        return this.type;
    }

}
```

But you may need to instantiate it like:

```
CommonClass<Person> cp = new CommonClass<Person>(Person.class);
```

If you are using Spring you can find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329) useful.

Comment: but i am using a spring @Autowired. just want to have it without a instantiating the constuctor with arguments. is there any way to do that?