# customized property name using jaxb annotations

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

I have a pojo definition like following:

```
class Pojo<T>
{
    private T entity;
    //setters and getters;
}
```

I want to serialize this pojo into json using jackson and jaxb annotations. I want the property name in json to be the type of T not the name "entity". I tried few things with jaxb annotations but nothing worked as expected.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try writing XmlAdapter for it. Also to get the type of generic T refer to other questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: For JAXB that would be an adapter to/from a `JAXBElement<T>`, with the runtime class of T being taken as the (local) element name. The JAXB annotation would be XmlAnyElement. - Not sure how to make j(ack)son work with this.