# How to Instantiate a class in a generic class in java

Tags: java, class, generics

```
public class DictionaryBase<T extends IData> {
    protected Map<String, T> mdic = new HashMap<>();

    protected T Add(String Name) {
        T objNew = new T();

        objNew.Name(Name);
        mdic.put(Name, objNew);

        return objNew;
    }
```

On new T() I have the Error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Also related: [How to get a class instance of generics type T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t).