# How to check that T is Collection of String using spring GenericTypeResolver?

Tags: java, spring, generics, reflection, collections

I have the following method:

```
public <T> void meth(T t){

}
```

Inside method I need to check that `t` is Collection of String(`List<String>`,  `Set<String>`, etc)

I understand that I can do it using reflection but I don't know how certainly.

**P.S.**

I believe that `org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver#resolveTypeArgument` need to resolve this problem but I don't understand which arguments to pass.

I have read this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/2674303 but I don't know how to apply it in my situation

Comment: No you can't do it using reflection, let us know otherwise :)

Comment: @Sleiman Jneidi please read topic update

Comment: the question was closed, so you can ask another one if you believe that the duplicate candidate doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @!Sleiman Jneidi You can help to reopen this. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Sleiman Jneidi please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271764/generictyperesolver-resolvetypearguments-returns-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reflection, you can test that `t` is a `Collection` but because of type erasure, you cannot check that it is a `Collection<String>`.

Here is still how to check that `t` is a `Collection`.

```
public <T> void meth(T t){
  if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass())) {
    System.out.println(true);
  } else {
    System.out.println(false);
  }
```

Note that you can still test individual elements of the collection but if you need to do that, you probably have a design problem.

**In answer to gstackoverflow's comment:**

I checked [this link](http://blog.xebia.com/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/) and I needed some time to understand it. The short answer is "*You cannot because the generic type is replaced with Object at compile time.*" (type erasure) **but** you can still get the information that is available at compile time and it **can** be enough depending on your use case.

For example :

```
private static Type[] getTypes(Object object) {
  return ((ParameterizedType)object.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
}
```

Sometimes, it will be useless :

```
Map<Integer, String> object = new HashMap<>();
for (Type actualTypeArgument : getTypes(object)) {
  System.out.println(actualTypeArgument);
}
```

Answer :

```
K
V
```

(And indeed, at compile time, you do not have any other information about generic type of `Map<K, V>`).

But sometimes, it can be useful :

```
public class IntegerList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
}

for (Type actualTypeArgument : getTypes(new IntegerList())) {
  System.out.println(actualTypeArgument);
}
```

Answer :

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

This one works because at compile time, the compiler *knows* that `IntegerList` is a `List<Integer>`.

In other words, you can access the information that is available at compile-time but not the information which is known at runtime.

Comment: You are wrong. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: @gstackoverflow You are giving a link which proves that it is not possible and that the developer has to give the class apart.

Comment: what about org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver#resolveTypeArgument ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/2674303

Comment: @gstackoverflow I checked your link and updated the answer.

Comment: Agreed. good information