# GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments returns null

Tags: java, spring, generics, reflection, type-erasure

I have the following code:

```
List strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("string");
System.out.println(GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(String.class, strings.getClass()));
```

It prints `null`.

I cannot understand this method signature.

I want to check that `strings` is parameterized with `String`.

How do you use `resolveTypeArguments` properly ?

### P.S.

My example just dummy.

### P.S.2

I know that spring can do something like this with Convertor interface

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc?  It says what the parameters mean and what a return value of null means. It'd be helpful to know which part you don't understand.

Comment: @Mark Peters  I need to check tha collection is collection<String>

Comment: Then you're out of luck I'm afraid, unless your concrete collection class extends `Collection<String>`.  In most cases, including your example above, the type parameters of `strings` has been *erased* at runtime.

Comment: @gstackoverflow The rather more interesting question is: why do you think you need to check whether the collection is a collection of strings?

Comment: @biziclop I have code which I cannot to change

Comment: Cannot change from what? It didn't work before, it doesn't work now.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis it works. Now I need to add validation. validation of T. I have requirement that if T is Collection of String(Set or List....it should be validated according concrete rules)

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you plan to do with that information.

Comment: _I know that spring can do something like this with `Converter` interface_ No. This is a limitation of the Java language. Spring might be doing _something_, but that's definitely not what you're asking about here.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis thus I can access generic type only if this exists in class declaration ?  implements List<String>

Comment: @gstackoverflow Do you need to apply the non-string validation rules if it's declared like  `Collection<Object> list = Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", "string3");`? In other words: why don't you just check that all the elements are strings?

Comment: @gstackoverflow More or less, yes. It has to be available somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This utility is made to look up *reified* type parameters.  What that means in this case is that the information must be available in the class itself.

The first parameter is the class you're trying to resolve the types of.  The second parameter is the superclass or interface the first class implements, which has generic type parameters.

Here would be one example for `Integer` (which implements `Comparable<Integer>`):

```
Class[] typeParams = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(
                            Integer.class, Comparable.class);
//typeParams would be [Integer.class]
```

In your example, the type parameter of `strings` has *not* been reified (it has been *erased*) and so this utility will return null, even if you were to fix how you were calling it (which would be `resolveTypeArguments(strings.getClass(), Collection.class)`)

Comment: When will a type be `erased`  and when will it be `reified`, may I ask. I'm new to Java.

Comment: @skyline75489: It's not the simplest thing to answer.  In general, reified types are those that make it into the `.class` file.  So it's types that need to be in the bytecode so that other code can compile against it.  e.g. my `Integer extends Comparable<Integer>` example, or `public List<String> getStrings() {`, etc.  For code to compile against these classes/methods, they need to know the actual type parameters, so they can't be erased.

Comment: Note that *reification* as I've used it can be a misnomer since there's now a push for proper reification of Java generics, not just the "poor man's reification" that I've described here, where the information makes it to the class file for linking purposes but is only available to the code through introspection (Reflection).  If proper reified types make it to the Java spec, we should probably stop calling the above reification.