# Nested Generics Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
class Field<T> {

  private final Class<T> type;

  public Field(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class Pick<V> {
  private final V value;
  private final Class<V> type;

  public Pick(V value, Class<V> type) {
    this.value = value;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

and the class the question is related to:

```
class PickField<T> extends Field<Pick<T>> {

  public PickField(Class<Pick<T>> type) {
    super(type);
  }
}
```

Now this seems to be accepted by the compiler. Unfortunately I do not know/understand how I could create a new instance of `PickField`, e.g. for  `String` picks.

This does - of course - not work:
`new PickField<String>(Pick.class)`

This is not allowed (I think I understand why):
`new PickField<String>(Pick<String>.class)`

So how to do it? Or does the whole approach somehow "*smell*"?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? There are a couple of patterns for doing one or two specific things with T, but if you need to do a bunch of stuff where the class of T actually matters, then the code probably does smell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think `PickField` should be parameterized with `Pick` instances only.

So doing this should be fine:

```
class PickField<T extends Pick<T>> extends Field<T> {

    public PickField(Class<T> c) {
        super(c);
    }
}
```

Then, you could just instantiate it with:

```
PickField<SomeSpecificPick> instance = new PickField<>(SomeSpecificPick.class);
```

where `SomeSpecificPick` is defined as:

```
public class SomeSpecificPick extends Pick<SomeSpecificPick> {

    public SomeSpecificPick(SomeSpecificPick value, Class<SomeSpecificPick> type) {
        super(value, type);
    }
}
```

More info (related with the topic):

- [Why is there no class literal for concrete parameterized types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ106)
- [How to get a class instance of generics type T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)
- [Erasure of Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is an error I think inside `SomeSpecificPick`? If the type parameter is the class itself this will give some strange circular reference, right?

Comment: No, there's no error. And this won't give circular references - this is the so-called self-reference type and the JDK actually defines few such, for example `Integer extends Comparable<Integer>`, etc. So just try the snippet out and get familiar with the links I shared. :)

Comment: Ok, seems to work after trying it out ;). One additional bonus question: what if the `PickField` would look like this: `PickField<T extends Pick<T>> extends Field<List<T>>` so that I have a list of picks? I can't manage to get the `super(type)` correct.

Comment: In such case, you will need a second type parameter. Should be something like: `PickField<T extends Pick<T>, L extends List<T>> extends Field<L>`

Answer (score 7):

There are various issues here.

Firstly as you point out, you cannot obtain the class of a parametrized type at compile time, since only one class is compiled for generic types, not one per given type parameter (e.g. the `Pick<String>.class` idiom does not compile, and doesn't actually make sense).

Again as you mention, parametrizing the `PickField<String>` constructor with `Pick.class` **only** will not compile again, as the signatures aren't matched.

You could use a runtime idiom to infer the right `Pick<T>` parameter, but that creates another problem: due to to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), your type argument for `T` will be unknown at runtime.

As such, you can parametrize your constructor invocation by explicitly casting, as follows:

```
new PickField<String>(
    (Class<Pick<String>>)new Pick<String>("", String.class).getClass()
);
```

... which will compile with an "unchecked cast" warning (`Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ? extends Pick> to Class<Pick<String>>`).

The **real** question is likely why do you need to know the value of `type` in your `Pick` class.

Comment: I do not need to know the type of the field, but the type of the pick. The field would be of type `Pick<String>` and the value of the `Pick` would be of type `String`. Edited the question for clarification.

Comment: @JDC Semantics IMO. The "smell" here as you mention it, is that you want to know the type your generic class `Pick` has been parametrized with, within the instance scope. This generally defiles the concept behind generics, and likely indicates a broader issue with your design.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but is not exactly a good one.
You need to create a method like this:

```
public static <I, O extends I> O toGeneric(I input) {
    return (O) input;
}
```

Then, you create the object:

```
new PickField<String>(toGeneric(Pick.class));
```

Like I said, not really a good way, since you basically just lie to the compiler, but it works.

Comment: This is equivalent to explicitly casting to `(Class<Pick<String>>)` and will generate another `unchecked cast` warning. No to mention the fact that, since it's presented as some general utility method, it might be misused **a lot** before someone starts finding bugs...

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass generics information as an argument, `Class<T>` is not enough. You need some extra power to achive that. Please see [this article](http://gafter.blogspot.com.uy/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html), where it is explained what a *super type token* is.

In short, if you have the following class:

```
public abstract class TypeToken<T> {

    protected final Type type;

    protected TypeToken() {
        Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

You could use it to store generics type information, such as `Pick<String>.class` (which is illegal). The trick is to use the superclass' generic type information, which is accessible via the [`Class.getGenericSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--) and [`ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments--) methods.

I have slightly modified your `Pick`, `Field` and `PickField` classes, so that they use a super type token instead of a `Class<t>`. Please see the modified code:

```
class Field<T> {

    private final TypeToken<T> type;

    public Field(TypeToken<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Pick<V> {

    private final V value;

    private final TypeToken<V> type;

    public Pick(V value, TypeToken<V> type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class PickField<T> extends Field<Pick<T>> {

    public PickField(TypeToken<Pick<T>> type) {
        super(type);
    }
}
```

And here is a sample usage:

```
TypeToken<Pick<String>> type = new TypeToken<Pick<String>>() {};
PickField<String> pickField = new PickField<>(type);
```

As `TypeToken` class is abstract, you need to subclass it (this explains the `{}` at the end of its declaration.