# How to get java class from generic method param?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I try to use the next method:

```
fun <T> put(value: T){
    val clazz = T::class.java
}
```

but has exception `Kotlin: Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal`

How obtain class from generic param?

What are other options except class can be passed as param?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: why do you want the class from the generics instead of `value` which obviously knows its own class?

Comment: @JaysonMinard I'm going to use a some sort of fabric and reflection for annotation processig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by

```
fun <T: Any> put(value: T){
    val clazz = value.javaClass
}
```

Comment: This may fail sometimes: consider `put(0 as Number)`, here `T` is `Number`, but `value.javaClass` will be `Integer`. If this is not what you want, use reified generics as stated in the other answer.

Comment: @hotkey I think more about Java compatibility. so this is what I want now

Comment: In that case you might as well make `clazz` the parameter.

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky you should make it clear in your question that you want the class of `value` and not of the generic type parameter, because your comments are to the contrary of what you originally stated.  And @hotkey is correct, you will get a wrong answer for the generic parameter, but a correct answer for the class of the parameter passed to the function.

Answer (score 6):

To access generic types within a function you need to make the types [*reified*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).
Since this is not natively supported by the JVM its only available in inlined functions:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> put(value: T) {
    val clazz = T::class.java
}
```

The type bound of `Any` is required to prevent some complications with nullable types.

Comment: what are restriction for using this method from Java code?

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky you can search for the 1000 examples of TypeReference, TypeToken, TypeRef and so on that do this similar type of thing from a Java viewpoint, you'll need to follow those patterns as Kotlin can make Kotlin nicer, but not make Java nicer.