# Autowiring generic types with constructor [Spring 4.2.5]

Tags: java, spring, dao, spring-4, genericdao

I'm new to Spring and trying to implement Generic DAO like in this article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-genericdao/ . I have couple of entities - ConcreteEntity1 and ConcreteEntity2. Also, I have classes

```
public interface GenericDao<T extends Serializable>  {
    public T get(long id);
    public List<T> get(String hql);
    public void remove(T persistentObject);
    public void add(T entity);
}
```

and

```
@Repository("hibGenericDao")
public class HibGenericDaoImpl<T extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> type;

    public HibGenericDaoImpl(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public T get(long id) {
        T entity;
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()) {
            entity = session.get(type, id);
        }
        return entity;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public List<T> get(String hql) {
        List<T> entityList;
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()) {
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            entityList = query.list();
        }
        return entityList;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void remove(T persistentObject) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()) {
            session.delete(persistentObject);
        }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void add(T entity) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to write service layer, and I want to autowire `HibGenericDaoImpl<ConcreteEntity1>` where field `type` contains `ConcreteEntity1.class`. Could you please say how to perform it without XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using spring, you can use the [GenericTypeResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html) utility class, as shown in this SO answer: [How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/48229)

You should be able to do something like:

```java
 this.type = (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), GenericDao.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your constructor with zero-arg constructor. Then you can get `T` type with reflection using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403976).