# Java generics: Why can't the compiler tell that this Class<T> object has the same type as the class of an object of this class' type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

Why do I need to cast the return of obj.getClass() to a Class<T> type when obj has type T?  This also generates a warning, which I have silenced.  But I feel like this shouldn't be necessary.  What's going on here?

```
public class DataSerialization<T> {
    private T deserializedObject;
    private Class<T> classObject;
    private String serializedObject = null;

    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DataSerialization(T obj) {
        this.deserializedObject = obj;
        this.classObject = (Class<T>) obj.getClass();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: What makes you think `deserializedObject` can't be a subclass of `T` instead of exactly `T`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: it doesn't return `Class<? extends T>` either

Comment: If you have an actual non generic object it will return a `Class<? extends Foo>`.  I don't think it works for generics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply put, it's because the `getClass` method returns `Class<?>`, no matter what type of class the object actually is. Even though the reference of type `Class<?>` is, in this instance, pointing to an object of type `Class<T>`, the method signature defines the return type as `Class<?>`, so that is what the compiler is expecting back.

To the compiler, you are casting a `Class<?>` to a `Class<T>`, and that flags a warning because there is no way to ensure, *by return type alone*, that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.  Is it reasonable to cast this to Class<T> here, since it will always be correct?  I don't like suppressing warnings because it usually means that I am doing something wrong, but I just can't think of a case where this won't be correct.

Comment: I suppose it is reasonable, though I recommend you look at this answer for ideas of how you can get around having to use a "T.class" sort of object. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3437930/4793951

Comment: @boshea what makes you think it will "always be correct"?  Why don't you think `deserializedObject` could be a subtype of `T`?

Comment: That is a good point, although for the purposes of my application, it will still behave correctly.  I have simplified this example a bit for brevity, but the objects that will be passed to this class are internal to the application and will not be subclassed (except in tests).

Comment: "it's because the getClass method returns Class<?>, no matter what type of class the object actually is." That's not true. `someExpr.getClass()` has the type `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of `someExpr`.