# How do I get a Class object from a method's type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a type-parameterized method but I can't call `getClass` on the type-parameterized parameter because it can be `null`, so the only solution I see is to get the `Class` from the type parameter itself, somehow:

```
public <T> Class myMethod(T obj)
{
    //can't do this: return obj.getClass() because null is permitted.
}
```

This method simply illustrates the problem. My actual method doesn't even return the parameter's class, but uses it in a different way. The core of the problem is this: Is there a way to get the `Class` object that represents the parameterized type of my method's parameter, without using `obj.getClass()` (because in case obj is `null`, I still need to know with what type parameter was the method invoked, for example: `<String>myMethod(null)` must return the `java.lang.String` class object).

**EDIT** This is not a duplicate of the said question because my class is not parameterized, only my method.

Comment: You can't, period. What is this intended to tell you that `getClass()` wouldn't?

Comment: @chrylis The method is an illustration. My actual method is not like that. I just reduced the problem to its core: I need to know the class of an object that may be null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a class instance of generics type T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Comment: Then you've simplified it too far.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think I did. The problem is perfectly demonstrated by this method.

Comment: Quite obviously not perfectly if it's not easily understood, and your "not a duplicate" suggests that you aren't quite getting some detail of Java generics.

Comment: @chrylis About not being a duplicate, the answers relies on the fact that a type can access its own type parameters. My class has no type parameters, so I can't use the answers given there. About my illustration not being enough to convey the nature of the problem, I'll try to edit and somehow be clearer, but all I can do is, more or less, repeat myself.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman The issue is the same regardless of where you declare the type parameter.

Comment: `if (obj == null) return null; return obj.getClass()` ??? (A null is a null, it has no type) You might also want to change the return type to `Class<T>`

Comment: @RC. `<String>myMethod(null)` must return `java.lang.String`, `<Byte>myMethod(null)` must return `java.lang.Byte`.

Comment: And where in the world do you expect the `<String>` information to come from?

Comment: @chrylis from the runtime method created when I invoke `myMethod` with the type parameter `<String>`. I was hoping the method would know at runtime the type parameter used to create it, afterall, java language constructs have a lot of metadata associated with them retained at runtime.

Comment: There *is* no "runtime method created".

Comment: I meant "the runtime version of the method, created by the compiler when I invoke myMethod with some type parameter".

Comment: @FinnTheHuman: There is only ever one version of the method.

Comment: @newacct oh. I didn't know that. What language I was thinking of? C++ I think. This is why it can't work then. Thank you, now I know the reason behind the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The core of the problem is this: Is there a way to get the `Class` object that represents the parameterized type of my method's parameter [...]

No. `Class` does not contain any information about the type parameter values. `Class` only contains data about the **definition** of the class, but not about a use of a type. In fact you cannot get this kind of information about a type parameter because of type erasure (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html (methods) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html (types)).

Comment: I see now. The compiler retains no information at all. Thank you, this answers my question

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to refactor the method to:

```
public <T> Class<T> myMethod(Class<T> theClass, T obj)
    // other stuffs
    return theClass;
}
```

but the caller already knows what T is, so the real question is, why do you need that.

=> community wiki

Comment: This is the approach I was trying to avoid. I'll refactor my method to `Class<?> myMethod(Class<?> cls, Object obj)`

Comment: The parameter `obj` is useless here as it is never used. The method in general is also pretty useless as it simply returns one of its arguments, so why not just use the passed argument directly instead of calling the method?

Comment: @newacct "other stuffs"