# [JAVA]How to get generic class typed name

Tags: java

I would like to get E class name in String value with java reflection.
For example, if i create Node typed in Person, getClassName() has to return "Person"

Someone can help me?

```
public class Node<E extends AbstractNode> {

String getClassName() {
    String name = ?? 
}

private String alias;

public Node() {

}
}


public abstract class AbstractNode {
}


public class Person extends AbstractNode {
private String name;
private String surname;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get your example and requirements, can you elaborate? How would `Person` and `Node<Person>` (which I guess you mean) be related? Where is `Node<Person>` used and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a class instance of generics type T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Comment: Node is a simply object that has got property but it isn't related with values that extend AbstractNode

Comment: It really depends on how you use `Node<E>`, e.g. if the node contains an element of type `E` you could just call `getClass()` on that, if you use concrete subclasses like `PersonNode extends Node<Person>` you can use reflection to get the type parameter etc. (note that due to type erasure that doesn't work with variables of type `Node<Person>` in most cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field to your `Node` class

```
private static final Class<T> type;
```

And add this to your constructor signature

```
public Node(Class type) {
   this.type = type;
}
```

Lastly, create the `getClassName` method in your `Node` class:

```
public String getClassName(){
    return this.type.getName();
}
```

Edit:
As a sidenote, your `AbstractNode` class is not really necessary (it doesn't do anything) and therefore neither is the `extend` in Person.