# JAVA Genericity Foo<Bar>.class

Tags: java, generics

I have a this generic :

```
public class GenericResponseEntities<T> extends BSResponseEntity {

    private List<T> returnedObject;

    /**
     * @return the returnedObject
     */
    public List<T> getReturnedObject() {
    return returnedObject;
    }

    /**
     * @param returnedObject
     *            the returnedObject to set
     */
    public void setReturnedObject(List<T> returnedObject) {
    this.returnedObject = returnedObject;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "GenericResponseEntities [returnedObject=" + returnedObject + "]";
    }
}
```

I use it like this :

```
public static <T> List<T> getGenericFromUrl(String url) {
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<GenericResponseEntities<T>> responseEntity;
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

try {
    responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, GenericResponseEntities<T>.class);

    if (responseEntity.getBody().getCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK.toString())) {
    list.addAll(responseEntity.getBody().getReturnedObject());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return list;
}
```

I have these errors on ligne : 
[image]

[image]

My question is how can I get the class of GenericResponseEntities.class ?

I can avoid these errors by using specific response entity (FooResponseEntity, BarResponseEntity ...). With this solution, I'll have so much specific response entity that specific server response.

Thanks

---

**Msf vtp** if I remove `<T>` in signature, I have this error :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Comment: You can't pass the class of a generics type. Just try GenericResponseEntities.class

Comment: Игорь Добровольський it isn't a dulicate. I want to get Foo<T>.class and not T.class

Comment: why your method signiture is "public static <T> List<T> getGenericFromUrl" and is not "public static List<T> getGenericFromUrl"?

Comment: Static methods cannot get to a generic parameter that way, @Msfvtp.

Comment: The `<T>` is also needed in the first method. By the way: **Do not post code or error messages as screenshots!**