# how to make spring bean extending a generic abstract class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For legacy and other reasons I'm not able to use JPA repositories. So I'm trying to build something similar for a project.
I have class MyEntityRepo

```
@Repository
public class MyEntityRepo extends CustomRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

}
```

And

```
public abstract class CustomRepository<T, ID> {

    private static final Logger LOG =LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRepository.class);

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private T _clazz;
    private String className;

    public CustomRepository() {             
        String className = _clazz.getClass().getName();
        if (className.contains(".")) {
            className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        }
        LOG.info("classname:{}", className);
    }
}
```

But when I'm starting the project, the spring framework is not able to create the bean as it is giving NullPointerException because _clazz field is null. Can somebody please explain how to achieve this?

Comment: How the _clazz can not be null while you're not setting in anywhere?

Comment: Looks like you don't need this `_clazz` fields. Try `String className = this.getClass().getName();` instead.

Comment: @sp00m I guess I'm not that good at writing variable names. className is actually showing name of entity class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the main problem is to get generic class.

You don't need to store `T _clazz;`

Try to use `org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver`

```
_clazz = (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), CustomRepository.class);
```

got the logic from [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

But actually Spring Data creates proxy from interface on fly. See [the example](http://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies)

Comment: order of answers in SOF isn't maintained, it's better to directly link the answer instead of linking the question if you want to refer a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got one more way which Hibernate uses.

```
    private Class<T> _clazz;
    private String className;
    public LybrateRepository() {
        this._clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        String className = _clazz.getName();
        if (className.contains(".")) {
            className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        }
        LOG.info("classname:{}", className);
     }
```

This is working for me :)