# Java: How to get the class type of generics at runtime?

Tags: java, generics

I have encountered the following scenario and I cannot find a simple solution.

## #1

```
public class Foo<T> {
    @Override
    public T bar() {
        // access T.class
    }
}
```

Java Generics always want the Generic type to be of type class. So it is natural to expect to access the class type. Why it doesn't work that way?

## #2

```
public class Foo<T> {
    @Override
    public T bar(Class C) {
        // automatically infer T to be of type `C`
    }
}
```

Is this possible in some way?

Elegant workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Iirc, Generic types "decay" to Object at runtime ("type erasure"?), so this isn't possible.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, but for #2 you may want to say `public T bar(T c)` (or maybe `public T bar(Class<? extends T> c)` )

Comment: for #1, that is not possible (unless you have the constructor manually store a reference to `Class<T>` ) due to type erasure. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437930/14955

Comment: [Please Go through following discussion, It may ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)