# How to convert Json result to Object when using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

Here is My Json Result Code:

```
      {
    "head": {
      "rspCode": 0,
      "rspMsg": "成功",
      "dataVersion": "",
      "appVersion": "",
      "deployVersion": "",
      "msgCount": ""
    },
    "body": {
      "orderNo": 166,
      "orderTime": "2017-07-27 09:30:48",
      "orderStatus": "Pending",
      "productsPart": [
        {
          "name": "iPhone",
          "total": 101,
          "orderProtList": [
            {
              "productSkuPrice": "101.0000",
              "productQuantity": "1",
              "productSku": "quantity"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    }
```

Here is My Entity Code,i am useing retrofit to rebuild my code structure ,but convert the json stumped me:

```
public class ResponseObj<T> {
private RespHeader head;
private T body;
........
(get set methods ignored)
}
```

RespHead.java:

```
public class RespHeader {
private String dataVersion;
private String appVersion;
private String deployVersion;
private String msgCount;
private int rspCode; //响应码
private String rspMsg;
.....
  (get set methods ignored)
 }
```

Here is the Body Class Content :

```
private int orderNo;
private String orderTime;
private String orderStatus;
private List<ProductsPartBean> productsPart;
...... 
(get set ignored)
```

I tried to use define custom GsonConverter to convert this JSON text.
Here are my steps:

```
public class GsonResponseConverter extends Converter.Factory {
private Gson gson;

public GsonResponseConverter(Gson gson) {
    this.gson = gson;
}


public static GsonResponseConverter create() {
    return create(new Gson());
}

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions") // Guarding public API nullability.
public static GsonResponseConverter create(Gson gson) {
    if (gson == null) throw new NullPointerException("gson == null");
    return new GsonResponseConverter(gson);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    TypeAdapter<?> adapter = this.gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
    return new CustomResponseConverter<>(this.gson);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    return super.requestBodyConverter(type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations, retrofit);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    return super.stringConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
}

private static class CustomResponseConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, ResponseObj<T>> {
    Gson gson;
    public CustomResponseConverter(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }
    @Override
    public ResponseObj<T> convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        String valueString = value.string();
        JSONObject obj = null;
        ResponseObj<T> resp = new ResponseObj();
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(valueString);
            if (obj.has("head")) {
                JSONObject obj_head = obj.getJSONObject("head");
                resp.setHead(gson.fromJson(obj_head.toString(), RespHeader.class));
            }
            if (obj.has("body")) {
                JSONObject obj_body = obj.optJSONObject("body");
                if (!InputHelper.isEmpty(obj_body) && obj_body.length() > 0) {
                    resp.setBody(gson.fromJson(obj_body.toString(), (Type) resp.getBody().getClass()));
                } else {
                    resp.setBody(null);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
            RespHeader header = new RespHeader();
            header.setRspCode(001);
            header.setRspMsg("server response error");
            resp.setHead(header);
            resp.setBody(null);
        }
        return resp;
    }
}
 }
```

my generic did not work because I Init a null ResponseObj that my body generic did not incoming, how can I do to resolve this question, what's the correct way to use it?

Comment: We would like you to add your currently attempted code to the question, even if you think it's wrong. Please [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: What exactly did you try? How it failed? Show some code.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Gson expects a well-defined Object model. For example, what are your `Head` and `Body`, and `ProductPart` classes?

Comment: @Lemonov  I add some code & modify my question

Comment: @cricket_007  I put some code & some desc, May be helpful

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in that `convert` method and debugging?

Comment: @cricket_007  yes ,i tried to follow the debug,found the error position ---> resp.getBody().getClass() is null ,so that i can't convert successfully

Comment: `resp = new ResponseObj()` has not had it's body variable set until after that line is executed. You cannot call `setBody` and `getBody` on the same line. You need to rethink your methods

Comment: @cricket_007 thx, I  changed the Entity Class  to resolve this, do not use the Generic Type

Answer (score 0):

Looking here...

```
resp.setBody(gson.fromJson(obj_body.toString(), (Type) resp.getBody().getClass()));
```

You're calling a getter and setter on the same line. The getter will always return null unless previously set (which it doesn't look like it is).

My suggestion would be something like so

```
public class ResponseObj<T> {
    private RespHeader head;
    private T body;

    public Type getType() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

With `resp.getType()` not relying on the Body (because the Object content/reference is a separate variable than the `Class` that represents it)

Worth mentioning: You can't get the class of a generic ... [How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Comment: thx for your answer, My Generic doesn't work, so I temporarily change the Entity to parse JSON Data, I will try this way in another time.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use  [Gson Converter for Retrofit 2](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson)

2) Then create POJO objects. You can use [this tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) . Check Source type: JSON and Annotation style: Gson

3) Create your requests using Retrofit 2 and use your POJO objects for response from server.

4) Profit!

Comment: thx for your answer, I was tried use Generic to build a common JSON converter, I used to do this before, I'm trying some new way to parse JSON Data

Comment: If you compare the code in the question with that link, you'll see the question actually modified the very same.