# Getting Entity Class in JPA and Repository Interface

Tags: java, jpa, interface, repository-pattern, parameterized-types

I am applying repository similar to Spring Data JPA where I would only create an interface of an entity repository:

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends Repository<Author, Long> {
}
```

I have this also Repository interface:

```
public interface Repository <T, ID extends Serializable> {
    List<T> findAll() throws Exception;
}
```

And its implementation, which I find it difficult to get the class name passed in as parameterized (T) to Repository :

```
public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Object> findAll() throws Exception {
        try {
            String namedQuery = "SELECT a FROM " + <How do I get the entity here as Author?> + " a";
            TypedQuery<Object> query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery, <How do I get the entity class as Author.class?>);

            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }
    }
```

}

I can't find way how to dynamically generate the entity class (ex. **Author**) to be created as part of **NamedQuery** string and an argument for **em.createNamequery()**.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possibly of use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've seen a lot of similar answer. I even followed the design and codes [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects), but none of them had worked. I always got ClassCastException. Thanks to [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools). It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching world wide web gave me similar approach and codes but none worked but [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

In the RepositoryImpl you can inject the entityInformation like this:

```java
@Autowired
private JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation;
```

and then use it for example like:

```java
String entityName = entityInformation.getEntityName();

Class<T> entityType = entityInformation.getJavaType();
```

Custom RepositoryFragments sadly can't autowire the JpaEntityInformation because they are singletons, so for generic fragments one would either need to pass the entity class with each method call and use `JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(clazz, entityManager)` or modify the BeanDefinition of the fragments and get the clazz using the injection point.