# is it possible to extend EnumMap with a Generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I am begining to believe it is not possible to extend `EnumMap` in Java because the super constructor is problematic.  A `super()` constructor must be called.

I have trialed several variations on the call to `super(...)` below.  They all give syntax errors.

- Is there a solution that will work as indicated below?

*Intented*:

```
 abstract public class EnumModel<K extends Enum<K>, T>  extends EnumMap<K, T>
{

    protected EnumModel( ) {

       super( K.class );    //  <-- "Cannot select from a type variable"
    }
}
```

For contrast, the example below with a specific Enum type will compile.  But only for Enum `Colour`.

```
enum Colour{
   RED, BLACK, BLUE;
}

abstract public class EnumModel<T>  extends EnumMap<Colour, T>
{

    protected EnumModel( ) {

       super( Colour.class );    //  <-- will compile
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no specific issue with `EnumMap` here. The problem is that `K.class` is a compiler error. You either have to pass the `Class<K>` in to the constructor, or *sometimes* you can use reflection. There are examples of both at the linked Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437897/2891664.

Comment: @Radiodef ... I was unaware of that question.  I found passing the class works for an EnumMap constructor.  I am not so sure this is a duplicat Question.  It is solved by some of the answers to the other question.  This a refinement or edge-case of the Generics problem in the other Q&A..