# Apache cxf port generic creation

Tags: java, generics, cxf, hierarchy

In my project I have to create some Soap web service clients I'm using apache cxf to create the ports and consume the web services I notice that the port creation I'm duplicating a lot of code so I create an abstract class like this

```
public abstract class WebServiceConsumerPort<P>{

    protected Class<P> port;

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServiceConsumerPort.class);

    public void createPort(String url, String timeoutS) {

        try {
            Long timeout = Long.parseLong(timeoutS);
            JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
            factory.setServiceClass(port.getClass());
            factory.setAddress(url);

            port = (Class<P>) factory.create();

            Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

            if (client != null) {

                log.info("Timeout WEB WERVICES: {}", timeout);

                HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
                HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
                policy.setAllowChunking(false);
                policy.setConnectionTimeout(timeout * 1000);
                policy.setReceiveTimeout(timeout * 1000);
                conduit.setClient(policy);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Peoblem creating the port", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to create the specific class to create the port:
For example I have the WebService1 with methods method1() and method2() and WebService2 with methods method3() and method4()

My consumer looks like:

```
public class WebService1Consumer extends WebServiceConsumerPort<WebService1Interface> {
        public void consumeMethod1() {
            port.method1();
        }

        public void consumeMethod2() {
            port.method2();
        }
    }
```

And another class looks like

```
public class WebService2Consumer extends WebServiceConsumerPort<WebService2Interface> {
        public void consumeMethod1() {
            port.method3();
        }

        public void consumeMethod2() {
            port.method4();
        }
    }
```

But in two classes say that Cannot resolve method in port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works, the code looks like:

```
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public abstract class WebServiceConsumerPort<P>{


    protected P puerto;
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServiceConsumerPort.class);

    public void creaPuerto(String url, String timeoutS, Class<P> tipoClase) {

        try {
            Long timeout = Long.parseLong(timeoutS);
            JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
            factory.setServiceClass(tipoClase);
            factory.setAddress(url);
            puerto = (P) factory.create();

            Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(puerto);

            if (client != null) {
                HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
                HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
                policy.setAllowChunking(false);
                policy.setConnectionTimeout(timeout * 1000);
                policy.setReceiveTimeout(timeout * 1000);
                conduit.setClient(policy);
            }
            nIntento = 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            puerto = null;
            nIntento++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to @ben-thurley with his answer in  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)