# Get domain type for custom repository in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Good afternoon, This is my first question here on StackOverflow.

I'm not an expert with the Spring framework and sometimes i get lost for a lot of time for problems that are relatively easy to solve, but this time i can't really get out of it.

I'm trying to implement a method inside a custom Spring Data Repository that should work with multiple Entities and perform some operations on the database, based on the presence of particular annotations on Entity's fields.

I've tried a lot of workarounds found on the internet but i'm not actually able to achieve the result i need. I'll try to be more specific:

This is an example Entity with the annotations:

```
@Data
@Entity
@MyAnnotation
public class User{

    @Id
    @MyDataAnnotation
    private Long id;

    @MyDataAnnotation
    private String firstName;

    @MyDataAnnotation
    private String lastName;

    private String userName;
    private int followers;
    private int following;
}
```

I have then inside the UserService class something like this:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    public void doSomethingOnUser(Long id){
        repository.myCustomMethod(id);
    }
}
```

For the UserRepository i did something like this, just very basic stuffs:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long>,MyCustomRepository<User,Long> {}
```

The i have the custom repo interface:

```
public interface MyCustomRepository<T,ID>{

    public void myCustomMethod(ID id);
}
```

And finally the implementation of myCustomMethod:

```
public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl <T,ID> implements MyCustomRepository{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;


    @Override
    public void myCustomMethod(Object id){

        User user = entityManager.find(User.class,id);

        List<Field> markedFields =   MyAnnotationProcessor.getAnnotated(user.getClass());

        //Here I'll manipulate the fields that i've obtained
        ...

        entityManager.persist(u);

        //And then i'm persisting the modified entity
    }
}
```

This is actually working with the User Entity, but i need to find a way to have it working for every domain type managed by a repository that extends MyCustomRepository.

For example if i have:

```
public interface WhateverRepository extends CrudRepository<WhateverClass,Long>,MyCustomRepository<WhatheverClass,Long>
```

myCustomMethod should do his stuffs anyway.

One thing i tried was to retrieve a `Class<T>` instance with this piece of code:

```
 private final Class<T> type;

 public MyCustomRepositoryImpl(Class<T> type) {
      this.type = type;
 }
```

And using type instead of User.class but it fails to load the ApplicationContext:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`
```

Thanks if you've read till here, hope you can give me some hints and if I wasn't clear enough please don't hesitate to ask me for further informations.

**Update:**

Following @amineT answer i tried to use the GenericTypeResolver provided by Spring, but instead of the types i actually get null.
The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html#resolveTypeArgument-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) states that if null is returned, it means that it wasn't able to resolve the type.

This is the code i used:

```
private final Class<?>[] genericType;

    public MyCustomRepositoryImpl(){
        this.genericType = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(getClass(), MyCustomRepositoryImpl.class);
    }
```

I think that somehow this "problem" is related to all the proxying that Spring is doing under the hood, but i don't have any precise idea at the moment.

If someone has any clues please write it down here, it'll be appreciated.

Comment: everything up to *"myCustomMethod should do his stuffs anyway."* seems logical, why do you want to inject a `Class` instance?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thanks for the reply. I need a Class<T> for the find method of entityManager and i also need to pass it to the annotation processor, maybe i should edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/3632030) helped me out. You're geting the NoSuchBeanDefinitionException because you're trying to inject a class type field but you didn't create one in Spring context. What you need to do is use Spring's GenericTypeResolver to find the generic type and process your data accordingly.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as soon as i have time I'll give it a shot and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, referencing from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/3632030) pointed by [@amineT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54078187/4758020), I've created a sample project to see if it suits your problem.

From my understanding, what you want should be to determine the type of the bean at runtime not the type of CustomRepositoryImpl. After I built my sample project, I find that your code is almost correct.

Here is a sample of what I would do to your code to make it work:

```
    @Override
    public void myCustomMethod(Class cls, Object id){

        Object user = entityManager.find(cls,id);

        List<Field> markedFields =   MyAnnotationProcessor.getAnnotated(cls);

        //Here I'll manipulate the fields that i've obtained
        ...

        entityManager.persist(u);

        //And then i'm persisting the modified entity
    }
```

Also, here is my [github](https://github.com/david-blacnet/spring-custom-repository-example) for the sample project I've created.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. I know that I could have done it in this way, but this implies that I have to call `myCustomMethod()` like this, in the UserService: `repository.myCustomMethod(User.class,id)` and my goal was to avoid passing the class as an argument. I would just like that everyone that is using my repo can  use it like a regular repo, calling it in this way: `repository.myCustomMethod(id)`.