# How to return T.class from given snippet?

Tags: java

```
private static User yaml() throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    return mapper.readValue(new File("user.yaml"), User.class);
}
```

Above code is specific to "User" class

I want to make it generic like this,

```
private static <T> T yaml() throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    return mapper.readValue(new File("user.yaml"), T.class);
}
```

But getting error at T.class,
Can anyone suggest on this please?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: How do you expect a `yaml()` call to know whether you want a `User`, an `Account` or an `Address`, when it's exactly the same call, with no argument to that method giving a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot obtain what you'd like to have.
You can, however, submit the `Class<T>` as an input parameter to `yaml(...)`.
You'll also have to consider the file name, as it won't be anymore only `user.yaml`.

A solution migth be to pass both as arguments

```
private static <T> T yaml(final Class<T> clazz, final String fileName) throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException {
    return MAPPER.readValue(new File(fileName), clazz);
}
```

I removed `ObjectMapper` creation from the method, as it is *thread-safe* and thus can be stored as a `static final` class field.

Comment: Got the solution:

private static <T> T yaml(Class<T> generic) throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
  return (T) mapper.readValue(new File("user.yaml"), generic);
 }

Comment: @user11175628 that's the same as the one I posted here. I also added the file name as parameter, as it will most likely change.