# DAO generic with hibernate parameterization

Tags: java, hibernate

So far I have this:

my DAO:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode;

import util.HibernateUtil;

public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> {
    private Class classe;
    private Session session;

    public AbstractDAO(){
        this.classe = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session getSession(){
        if(this.session == null || !this.session.isOpen()){
            this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }
        return this.session;
    }

    public void save(T t){
        getSession().beginTransaction();
        getSession().save(t);
        getSession().close();
    }

    public void delete(T t){
        getSession().beginTransaction();
        getSession().delete(t);
        getSession().close();
    }

    public void alter(T t){
        getSession().beginTransaction();
        getSession().update(t);
        getSession().close();
    }

    public List<T> findAll(T t){
        return getSession().createCriteria(this.classe).list();
    }

         /**
     * Metodo responsavel por recuperar todos os objetos de uma tabela da base de dados de acordo
     * com o exemplo passado.
     *
     * @param filtro
     * @param matchMode
     * @param ignoreCase
     * @return lista
     */
    public List<T> findByExample(T filtro, MatchMode matchMode, boolean ignoreCase){
        org.hibernate.criterion.Example example = org.hibernate.criterion.Example.create(filtro);

        if(matchMode != null){
            example = example.enableLike(matchMode);
        }

        if(ignoreCase){
            example = example.ignoreCase();
        }

        return getSession().createCriteria(this.classe).add(example).list();
    }
}
```

my hibernate util:

```
public class HibernateUtil {  

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    static {  
        try {  
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml  
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();  
        } catch (Throwable ex) {  
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed  
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);  
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);  
        }  
    }  

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {  
        return sessionFactory;  
    }  

}
```

meu main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Departamento depart = new Departamento();
    AbstractDAO<Departamento> padrao = new DepartamentoDAO();
    padrao.findAll(depart);
    System.out.println(padrao);
}
```

I have this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
>     at dao.AbstractDAO.(AbstractDAO.java:16)  at
>   dao.DepartamentoDAO.(DepartamentoDAO.java:17)   at
>   view.eeee.main(eeee.java:12)

Not sure if I did it best if someone could help me how to adjust the code

Comment: Please use correct upper case in title.

Comment: what ? i dont understand

Comment: Please see Ben Thurley's solution of [How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Comment: Sentencies starting with a upper case letter. In case of your comment. "**W**hat?" instead of "what?" Please check your text for such cases.