# Get parameter class in generic java method

Tags: java, generics

In a regular method I can get parameter class like this:

```
public void methodA(String param)
{
    Class typeA = String.class;
    // or
    Class typeB = param.getClass();
}
```

In a generic method this still works:

```
public <T> void methodB(T param)
{
    Class type = param.getClass();
}
```

But what about this:

```
public <T> void methodC(ArrayList<T> param)
{    
    //Class type = ??? 
    //How to get T class?
    //Something like "Class type = T" would be nice
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-do-i-get-a-class-instance-of-generic-type-t?rq=1) solves your problem?

Comment: The sanest solution is to get out `param.get(0).getClass()` to do something equivalent to your `methodB`.  That isn't _actually_ sane, it's just the best you can hope for.

Comment: Why do you need the `Class` object?  Usually in generic methods where the `Class` object is required, it's added as a parameter to the method, typed as `Class<T>`.

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like there is no "easy" way. I suppose I will send it as an extra parameter then. (That is also my current workaround, but I thought perhaps there was a simple solution to avoid the extra parameter.)