# Instantiating generic objects in Java

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to instantiate generic objects in Java as does in the following code fragment? I know that it is possible in C#. But, I haven not seen a similar mechanism yet in Java.

```
// Let T be a generic type.
T t = new T();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that doesn't work in Java, due to type erasure. By the time that code is executing, the code doesn't know what `T` is.

See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) more more information about Java generics than you ever wanted :) - in particular, see the [Type Erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3) section.

If you need to know the type of `T` at execution time, for this or other reasons, you can store it in a `Class<T>` and take it in the constructor:

```
private Class<T> realTypeOfT;

public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
  realTypeOfT = clazz;
}
```

You can then call `newInstance()` etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid not. Generic types in Java are erased - they're used at compile time, but aren't there at runtime (this is actually quite handy in places).

What you can do is to create a new instance from the Class object.

```
Class<T> myClass;
T t = myClass.newInstance();
```