# cannot instantinate generic type instance in Java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

I've a little trouble. I cannot instantinate generic type instance in default constructor.
here is my class

```
public class MyClass<U extends MyUser> {
    private U user;

    public U getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(U user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public MyClass() {
        this.user = new U();
    }
}
```

in code line `this.user = new U()` I'm getting exception

> cannot instantinate type U

. How can I create new instance of U?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a type when instantiating your User. That type needs to be a MyUser or subtype of MyUser.

```
public class MyClass<U extends MyUser>{
private U user;
public U getUser(){
return this.user;
}

public void setUser(U user){
  this.user=user;
}

public MyClass() {
    this.user=new MyClass<U>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java generics do not know the types of their templated parameters at runtime. Therefore, in your example, the runtime type of `U` is not known, so the constructor cannot execute `new U()`.

You will need to pass in the type of `U` (something like `Foo.class`) to the conctructor in order for it to know how to create a new obejct of type `U`.

Comment: could you write creation of type instance for my code? Thanks in advance.