# Create an Object using a Generics type Java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instantiating a generic class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

I am studying Generics Java because I would like to implement this:

I have 2 classes that use 1 common class, and in this common class I want to create an Object of a generic class. Here there is a piece of my code so It will be simplest.

```
//MyFirstClass.java 
class MyFirstClass{ 
    ...
     MyExpandableListAdapter<FirstFilter> mAdapter = new   MyExpandableListAdapter<FirstFilter>();
    ...
 }

//MySecondClass.java
class MySecondClass{ 
    ...
     MyExpandableListAdapter<SecondFilter> mAdapter = new   MyExpandableListAdapter<SecondFilter>();
    ...
}

//common class MyExpandableListAdapter.java
public class MyExpandableListAdapter<E extends Filter> extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements Filterable {
    private E filter;
    ...
    public Filter getFilter(){
        if (filter== null)
            filter = new <E>(); // Here I want to create an Object, but I get an error on <E>
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do it? How I could do it?
Please, help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way in which generic is implemented, it's completely impossible to instantiate a generic parameter as you're trying to do here.

The usual alternative is to use some sort of factory, i.e. a class that implements an interface similar to:

```
interface Factory<E> {  
    E newInstance();
}
```

This way, you'd have different implementations of the factory for different versions of `E`, and the compiler would check that you're passing in one of the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to E at run-time in the way you want. You can hack around this, but it's a bit messy:

```
protected Class<E> filterClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MyExpandableListAdapter() {
    filterClass = (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

After you have the class you can use reflection to create an instance. See [this tutorial for more information](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

You should consider if the added complexity is worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved using the solution posted by Andrzej Doyle. I think that I will try also your idea to curiosity :)
It is another good solution :) Have a nice day ;)