# Java Passing in Type as Function Parameter

Tags: java

I come from a Python background and in Python you can pass in the type of an object as a parameter. But in Java you cannot do this, any tips on how to get something like this working?

```
private void function(Type TypeGoesHere)
    Stock s = new TypeGoesHere();
    s.analyze();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i pass Class as a parameter in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872978/how-do-i-pass-class-as-a-parameter-in-java)

Comment: More generally, searching "Java reflection" (like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)) should give you some relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not support Python’s way of referencing functions and classes. To achieve this behaviour, you have to use two advanced techniques: generics and reflection. Explaining these concepts is beyond the scope of a SO answer. You should read a Java guide to learn about them.

Yet here is an example how this would look like, assuming that the given class has a no-argument constructor:

```
public <T extends Stock> void analyzeNewStock(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
  Stock s = clazz.newInstance();
  s.analyze();
}
```

Then call this function with `analyzeNewStock(MyStock.class)`.

As this is a rather complicated and error-prone approach, you’d rather define an interface that creates `Stock` instances:

```
public interface StockProvider {
  Stock createStock(String value);
}

public class MyStockProvider implements StockProvider {
  private final String valueTwo;

  public MyStockProvider(String valueTwo) {
    this.valueTwo = valueTwo;
  }

  @Override
  public Stock createStock(String valueOne) {
    return new MyStock(valueOne, valueTwo);
  }
}

public class MyOtherClass {
  public void analyzeNewStock(StockProvider provider) {
    provider.createStock("Hi!").analyze();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    analyzeNewStock(new MyStockProvider("Hey!"));
  }
}
```

Comment: How would the code look like if there are parameters being passed into the Stock class?

Comment: @budi I updated the second example. The implementation depends on whether the parameters always have the same value (`valueTwo`) or can be different (`valueOne`).

Comment: @budi If you want to use the first example (I would not advise to do so), you would write e. g. `clazz.getConstructor(String.class, String.class).newInstance("Hey", "ho");`.

Comment: I got it working, your code works great, thanks! It's disappointing that there's no easier way to do this in Java (I miss Python dearly).

Comment: There is no need for generics in this answer.  If you follow what erasure will do to this code, simply passing in a base type argument of "Stock" will have the same effect as the generics version.

Comment: @kervin `Class` is a generic class, so you’ll have to deal with generics (if you don’t want to use raw types). `Class<Stock>` would only accept `Stock.class` AFAIS. If you want to also allow `Stock`’s subclasses, you’ll have to use `Class<? extends Stock>`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can pass a Class. You can do it like this:

```
private void function(Class c)
```

This is not very common procatice though. You can probably get wha you need by looking into Strategy pattern, or proper use of Object Oriented Programming (polymorphism).

If you are looking for a way to build some objects, look into Factory pattern.

If you want to create a generic class- look into this detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090488/1611957

Answer (score 1):

You could use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). For example:

```
private <T> void function(Class<T> clazz) {
    try{
        T t = clazz.newInstance();
        //more code here
    }catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `Class<T> clazz` shows what type to instantiate. The `try/catch` is just to prevent errors from stopping your code. The same idea is expanded in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9689909/3761440). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434214/3761440).

However, I'm not really sure why you would want to do this. There should easily be a workaround using a simple interface. Since you already know that you want an object with type `Stock`, you could pass an implementation of the interface. For example:

```
//interface to implement
public interface Stock {
    public void analyze();
}

//rewrite of function
private void function(Stock s){
    s.analyze();
}
```

And using two ways to call `function`:

```
//first way
public class XYZ implements Stock{
    public void analyze(){
        //some code here
    }
}

//calling the function
function(new XYZ());

//second way
function(new Stock(){
    public void analyze(){
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Generics alone will not do what he wants.  Generics are compile-time, what he wants is more reflection than Generics.

Comment: Fair enough, but either way, an interface is probably better.