# Instantiating Generic Object

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have a method that accepts a subtype of Button2. This method does some calculations and creates buttons to be place in an ArrayList so that they are arranged in a graphical way. Here's my code:

```
public void createButtonArray(ArrayList<? extends Button2> buttonList,
        int xLength, int yLength, int width, int height, int inset) {

    // The total size for the inset, or spaces between buttons
    int totalInset = (xLength - 1) * inset;
    // The total height = height of buttons + size of insets
    int totalHeight = totalInset + 5 * height;
    // ... More calculations
```

The it comes to this. I don't know how to say this following line because the compiler gives me syntactical errors. How do I create a button that's a subtype of Button2?

```
Button2<?> button = new Button2(xpos, ypos, width, height);
buttonList.add(button);
counter++;
```

I've also tried this:

```
buttonList.add(new <? extends Button2>(xpos,ypos,width,height));
```

which also gives me an error. How can I create this button to add to my generic ArrayList?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a generic class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

Comment: Every type is a subtype of itself, so `Button2 button = new Button2(...)` will work if `Button2` is a concrete type with a visible constructor.  `Button2<?> button` will not work if `Button2` does not have a type parameter.

Comment: Button2 button = new Button2(xpos, ypos, width, height);
buttonList.add(button);
leads to a compiler error: The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Button2) in the type ArrayList<capture#1-of ? extends Button2> is not applicable for the arguments (Button2)

Comment: you can only add a list that accepts super-types, not sub-types, of the type you're adding.  A list that can have any subtype of `Button2` **added** to it has type `List<? super Button2>`, while a list that can have any subtype of `Button2` **gotten** from it has type `List<? extends Button2>`.

Comment: see [Covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Java) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add any objects (except null) into `ArrayList<? extends Button2>`, but you can pass just `ArrayList<Button2>` to your function and then do `buttonList.add(new Button2(xpos,ypos,width,height))`.