# How to Instantiate a Java parameter type

Tags: java

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<O, PK extends Serializable>{

protected EventDispatcher eventDispatcher;

protected GenericDao<O,PK> dao;

protected ApplicationPublisher publisher;

protected State state;

protected InternalPublisher internalPublisher;

@PostConstruct
private void initialise(){
    eventDispatcher.addHandler(this);
}

protected <T extends GenericDao<O,PK>> AbstractRepository(T dao, State state, ApplicationPublisher publisher, InternalPublisher internalPublisher, EventDispatcher eventDispatcher){
    this.dao = dao;
    this.state = state;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.internalPublisher = internalPublisher;
    this.eventDispatcher = eventDispatcher;
}


@HandleEvent
private void handleDataContributorCreatedEvent(DataContributorDeletedEvent event){

    List<O> stats = new ArrayList<O>();

    for(int x = -1 ; x < 50 ; x++){

        for (int y = 0 ; y < 360 ; y = y + 5){
            stats.add(**Need to instantiate paramater type O here**);
        }   

    }
    dao.save(stats);
}
```

}

Within the event handler method - I want to be able to create an instance of the Parameter Type, O - but not sure how do this. Any help regarding the best approach would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that because of [type erasure in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Basically, there's no way to know the class of your `O` parameter in runtime.

As @pescis suggested, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java) are described ways to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a constructor accepting a parameter

```
Class<O> class
```

object store it and when you need it use

```
class.getConstructor() and constructor.newInstance
```

methods of the reflection API. That's because the generic types exist only on compile time, in bytecode all that stuff are just plain Objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the List instance you have, something like this :

```
Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) stats.getGenericInterface()[0];
```

then you can `clazz.newInstance()`.

Disclaimer : not tested, but i'm pretty sure i've read somewhere that it works.