# Creating new instance of generic Type in java

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to create new instance of generic type using java , i have used type resolver to get the parametrized and i was able to get it. type but whenever i call this.myclass.newInstance() an instantiation exception is raised. 
i know the same question is asked but no answer has solved my problem.
Pre Thanks.

Comment: How about MyClass.newInstance()?

Comment: What *exact* exception was raised? Type erasure actually makes constructing an instance of a generic type with reflection relatively straightforward - you don't need to specify the type arguments because the object isn't aware of them.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Comment: Your question is missing two important things: Post your **Code** and the **full stack trace**