# How do I get the `.class` attribute from a generic type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090458/1353391) describes how to create an instance of `T` in the `Generic<T>` class.  This involves passing in a `Class<T>` parameter to the `Generic` constructor and callin the `newInstance` method from that.

A new instance of `Generic<Bar>` is then created, and the parameter `Bar.class` is passed in.

What do you do if the generic type parameter for the new `Generic` class is not some known class like `Bar` but is itself a generic type parameter?  Suppose I had some other class `Skeet<J>` and I wanted to create a new instance of `Generic<J>` from inside that class.  Then, if I try to pass in `J.class` I get the following compiler error:

```
cannot select from a type variable.
```

Is there any way around this?

The specific bit of code triggering the error for me is:

```
public class InputField<W extends Component & WidgetInterface>
                                                 extends InputFieldArray<W>
{
  public InputField(String labelText)
  {
    super(new String[] {labelText}, W.class);
  }
  /* ... */
}

public class InputFieldArray<W extends Component & WidgetInterface>
                                                                 extends JPanel
{
   /* ... */
  public InputFieldArray(String[] labelText, Class<W> clazz)
                          throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
  {
    /* ... */

    for (int i = 0 ; i < labelText.length ; i++) {
      newLabel = new JLabel(labelText[i]);
      newWidget = clazz.newInstance();
      /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

The error happens, because I can't write `W.class`.  Is there some other way of passing in the same information?

Comment: Your question maybe more clear if you post a code example (i.e. the one that triggers the compiler error).

Comment: But you must be having the class name in `Skeet<J>` right? You need to pass that class to the `Generic` constructor. If you show actual code, we can help you better.

Comment: you can't use `J.class` because of [type erasure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-erasure). But you can get concrete `Class` variable on `Skeet<J>` construction

Comment: On the linked question, Jon didn't literally mean `T.class` - you can't use `.class` on type parameters. He meant a `Class<T>` would need to be passed in by the caller.

Comment: I know.  I, however, would like to be able to pass in the class of `J`.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Using `.class` on a type parameter isn't allowed - because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), `W` will have been *erased* to `Component` at runtime. `InputField` will need to also take a `Class<W>` from the caller, like `InputFieldArray`:

```
public InputField(String labelText, Class<W> clazz)
{
    super(new String[] {labelText}, clazz);
}
```

Comment: Base on the given type erasure link, the generic type will be replaced by type `Object` since no bound is given in this case. So because type `Class` is the subclass of `Object`, I think in this case we won't be able to call `.class`. But what if the given bound is not `Object` (like `<? extends Foo>`, I mean the method `.class` should still be selectable in this case. I'm a little bit confused here. @Paul Bellora

Comment: @Dreamer `.class` isn't a method or anything that can be dynamically resolved at runtime. It's a compile-time construct used to statically get the `Class` object representing an explicit concrete type.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using the Gson library, you can get the type of `T` easily by using `TypeToken`. The class documentation is available [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html):

I did it like this:

This is my class definition:

```
public class ManagerGeneric <T> {}
```

This is in my method:

```
// Get the type of generic parameter
Type typeOfT = new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();
// Deserialize
T data = gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT);
```

Answer (score 13):

W may not be available due to type erasure. You should require that a `Class<W>` is passed into the method. You get a class object and its generic ensures that only `W` and no subclass is passed in, due to covariance.

```
public InputField(String labelText, Class<W> cls)
{
    super(new String[] {labelText}, cls);
}
```

will take `W.class` but not `WSubtype.class`.