# Why Jackson,GSON... doesn't use generics but pass class object to deserialize object

Tags: java, generics

For example: 
Why not:

`Foo result = mapper.readValue<Foo>(jsonStr);`

instead of

`Foo result = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Foo.class);`

What is the limitation of Java Generics that prevent them from using it ?

Comment: What limitation do you speak?

Comment: There is a limitation. @RomanC The limitation is "Cannot select from a type variable". So you can't call `T.class` to get the class which is needed for the next method(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

#### It's a Java Generics limitation

The limitation is `Cannot select from a type variable`. So you can't call `T.class` to get the class-object of T which is needed for the next method(s).

## Long answer

Take a look at the implementation

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)
    throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
{
    return (T) _readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createParser(content), _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
}

public JavaType constructType(Type type) {
    return _fromAny(null, type, EMPTY_BINDINGS);
}
```

They need to pass the `valueType` at

```
_typeFactory.constructType(valueType)
```

This is not possible with generics.

#### Example

I've tried the following

```
private <T> T readValue(String content)
{
    return constructType(T.class);
}

private JavaType constructType(Type type)
{
    //construct type somehow
}
```

This doesn't compile. It says `Cannot select from a type variable` on T (line 3). Now with the Class argument:

```
private <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> clazz)
{
    return constructType(clazz);
}

private JavaType constructType(Type type)
{
    //construct type somehow
}
```

This would compile successfully.

#### Also see

[How do I get the `.class` attribute from a generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255117/how-do-i-get-the-class-attribute-from-a-generic-type-parameter)