# Java: How to create a new instance from a TypeReference object?

Tags: java, types, casting, jackson, instantiation

I have a method that accepts a [`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) and returns an object of the referenced type, but in a certain case I want to just return a new instance of that type.

Example:

```
public <T> T getProperty(String property, TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
    try {
        return someInstanceOfReferencedType();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return ???;
    }
}
```

How can I instantiate `<T>` using `typeReference`? I can get the `Type` from it, but not sure what to do from there...

Comment: Why a `TypeReference<T>`? Why not a `Class<T>`?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Comment: Using a TypeReference because it may be, for example, a `Map<Foo, Bar>` type and I want to retain that.

Comment: If it's a `Map`, what are you going to instantiate?

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess I should just throw an exception in this case.

Comment: Not necessarily. Some libraries choose to have default implementations. Note that a `HashMap<String, Double>` is the same as a `HashMap<Foo, Bar>` at the time you instantiate it. Jackson needs the type reference in order to know how to deserialize nested JSON elements. If you're not doing that, I don't see you needing the type reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an instance of TypeReference as:

```
List<String> l1 = new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>() {}.newInstance();
```

So you can call getProperty method as:

```
List<String> list = getProperty("property1",new TypeReference <>(){});
//Specify List<> in <> of TypeReference.
```