# Creating an empty List<String> based on Generics

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, predicate

So I am currenty trying to implement a method which does some filtering on lists regardless of their actual type. Here is the actual method:

```
public static <T extends List<String>> T filterList(T list, Predicate <String> predicate) {

    T newList = ???
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (predicate.test(s)) newList.add(s);
    });
    return newList;

}
```

So the generic type T is basically the some implementation of List such as ArrayList or LinkedList and regardless of their actual implementation I want to do some filtering through a Predicate passed as parameter. The return type of the method is the same as the list which is passed as a parameter. But how is it possible to instanciate an empty List based on T (see line 2)? 
To show you how the method is intended to be used i provided an example. The following example would filter an ArrayList based on the length of the containing Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
listOfNames.add("stackoverflowuser");
listOfNames.add("sitaguptana");
listOfNames.add("nyan cat");
listOfNames.add("pedro");

Predicate<String> lengthUnderTen = (string) -> string.length() < 10;

ArrayList <String> result = filterList(listOfNames,lengthUnderTen);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantiating a generic class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

Comment: Can someone please provide an example

Comment: @solomid look at the link giorashc or I posted

Comment: I don't  think this answers my question

Comment: If it does could you please provide an quick example ?

Comment: Why are you even bothering with a generic type? is `public static List<String> filterList(...){}` not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could modify your method as

```
public static <T> List<T> filterList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {

    return list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It looks clean because it works for any type of List, not only for List<String>. This method will be more generic.

Comment: Works fine and is more clean!

Answer (score 4):

If I am understanding your question correctly, then I don't see why you need to use generics at all here.

The following function will accept any class that extends List as a parameter e.g. an ArrayList, LinkedList etc.:

```
public static List<String> filterList(List<String> list, Predicate<String> predicate) {
    return list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Full example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> example1 = new ArrayList<>();
        example1.add("abc");
        example1.add("ghe");

        LinkedList<String> example2 = new LinkedList<>();
        example2.add("foo");
        example2.add("bar");

        List<String> result1 = filterList(example1, s -> s.contains("a"));
        List<String> result2 = filterList(example2, s -> s.contains("f"));
    }

    public static List<String> filterList(List<String> list, Predicate<String> predicate) {
        return list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the caller pass in a `Supplier<T>` as well.

```
public static <T extends List<String>> T filterList(T list, Predicate <String> predicate, Supplier<T> listCreator) {

    T newList = listCreator.get();
    list.forEach(s -> {
       // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the class by reflection by passing a `List<String>` as parameter.
In fact you don't need to specify any wildcard for your list.

```
public static List<String> filterList(List<String> list,  Predicate<String> predicate) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    List<String> newList = list.getClass()
                               .newInstance();
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (predicate.test(s)) newList.add(s);
    });
    return  newList;
}
```

But note that a cleaner way would be to use a stream to collect the new List if the implementation doesn't matter :

```
public static List<String> filterList(List<String> list,  Predicate<String> predicate) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

  return list.stream()
             .filter(predicate)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a base class that already allows you to cleanly program to interface. You could design this API method to return a `List` object, keeping the generic type at element level.

Please note that this pattern is already provided by the standard API (List/Collection + Stream), so you shouldn't need to recreate it. - see note at bottom.

If you **do not have any constraint regarding the type of list** returned by the method, then it's this implementation's choice which list type it returns (using array list below):

```
public static <T> List<T> filterList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {

    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>(); //You can choose a different type here
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (predicate.test(s)) newList.add(s);
    });

    return newList;
}
```

If you leave it to your caller to choose **what type of list is created**, then perhaps you should take a factory:

```
public static <U, T extends List<U>> T filterList(T list, 
      Predicate<U> predicate, Supplier<T> newListFactory) {

    T newList = newListFactory.get(); //You can choose a different type here
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (predicate.test(s))
            newList.add(s);
    });

    return newList;
}
```

**Note**: this pattern is already provided by the collections API:

```
java.util.stream.Stream.filter(Predicate<? super T>)
```

This allows you to do exactly the same thing, except that the creation of the returned list (say, you ran `collect(Collectors.toList())`)