# Extending a Binary Search Tree to a Red-Black Tree

Tags: java, inheritance

I have implemented a simple Binary Search Tree. I want to create a subclass Red-Black Tree, but I'm having problems. The code for the BST is as follows, with the irrelevant details removed. The BST works perfectly fine.

**Node:**

```
public Node {
    private int key;

    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node parent;

    public Node(int key){
        // init
    }
}
```

**BST:**

```
public BinarySearchTree {
    protected Node root;

    public void insert(int key){
        Node insertNode = new Node(key); // This is problematic
        // perform insertion
    }
}
```

I need to subclass `Node` to add a color property:

**RbtNode**:

```
public RbtNode extends Node {
    private boolean isBlack;

    public RbtNode(int key){
        // init
    }
}
```

And the `RedBlackTree` class

**RedBlackTree**

```
public RedBlackTree {

    public void insert(int key){
        super.insert(key);
        // perform RBT fixes
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to reuse the `insert` method of `BinarySearchTree`, but since it inserts a `Node` and not an `RbtNode`, it won't work.

A solution I came up with is to create a separate method `createNode(int key)` that I can override, but I would need to do quite a bit of typecasting when accessing/manipulating nodes on the subclass.

Is there any cleaner solution, preferrably one without typecasts?

**EDIT:** The problem is when calling `super.insert` from the subclass (RedBlackTree), it uses the parent's `root` field instead of the subclass's `root` field.

Comment: You could keep `RbtNode` object in `RedBlackTree` and not reuse `protected Node root` from `BinarySearchTree`

Comment: This old question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Comment: You need a null check when insert the key value pair and where (the node) to insert it. Also use @Override instead on insert.

Comment: @miradham The BST insert uses the `root` field directly. So when calling `super.insert` from RBT, the method uses the parent's `root` instead of the subclass. What can I do about it?

Comment: @paisanco It's not really about generics but the `Node` itself. The generics takes care of the value contained, not the subclassing of the node.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the tree logic you want to reuse to a generic super class with a factory method for `Node` creation:

```
public abstract class AbstractBinarySearchTree<T extends Node> {
    protected T root;

    public T insert(int key) {
        T insertNode = newNode(key);
        // perform insertion
        return insertNode;
    }

    public abstract T newNode(int key);
}
```

Concrete BST just needs the factory method to complete it:

```
public class BinarySearchTree extends AbstractBinarySearchTree<Node> {
    @Override
    public Node newNode(int key) {
        return new Node(key);
    }
}
```

RBT overrides the insert method and factory method:

```
public class RedBlackTree extends AbstractBinarySearchTree<RbtNode> {
    @Override
    public RbtNode insert(int key){
        RbtNode node = super.insert(key);
        // perform RBT fixes
        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public RbtNode newNode(int key) {
        return new RbtNode(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep `root` node for `BST` and `RBT` seperately and move common logic to single insert method

```
public class BST {
    private Node root;
    protected Node createNode(int key) {
        //System.out.println("create BST node");
        return new Node(key);
    }
    public void insert (int key) {
        insert(key, root);
    }
    protected Node insert(int key, Node root) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = createNode(key);
            return root;
        }
        if (key > root.key) {
            root.left = insert(key, root.left);
        } else if (key < root.key) {
            root.right = insert(key, root.right);
        }
        return root;
    }
 }
```

`RBT` will have to override `createNode` and `insert`

```
public class RBTree extends BST {
    private RBNode root;
    @Override
    protected RBNode createNode(int key) {
        System.out.println("create RB node");
        return new RBNode(key);
    }
    @Override
    public void insert(int k) {
        super.insert(k, root);
    }
}
```