# How do I build a heap sort class without a specific type?

Tags: java, data-structures, heapsort

here is the program I am asked to do.  I have already   done it with a specific type (int) but doing it with an object type is quite confusing.

```
public class HeapSort
{ 
    private Object[] data;
    private int partition;

    HeapSort(Object[] data);  // Class Constructor
    HeapSort(int size);       // Class Constructor

    public Object[] sort()           // Sorts the data
    public void insert(Object item); // Insert in Heap
    public Object extractMin();    // Remove from Heap

    private void bubbleUp()
    private void bubbleDown()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantiating a generic class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

Comment: This [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) on generics will help you to understand how to create a generic `HeapSort`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use generics in Java to write type independent programs. Arrays and generics do not play very well together. Therefore, instead of a bare array, you may consider using an `ArrayList` with a generic type. `ArrayList` is internally an array only which has the intelligence to allocate a new larger array and copy everything from the original array to the new array when the original array runs out of space. While it abstracts away all these complexities from the programmer, it does incur a cost. Therefore, while using `ArrayList` with generics to build a heap sort program, make sure you use the `ensureCapacity` method or the appropriate constructor to specify the expected size of the array. Finally for comparing the generic objects, you need to pass an apprpriate `Comparator` implementation.

Comment: I get that, but in this class we haven't even covered that yet. isn't there another way to use an object from a class method without the type operator? ::