# What's wrong with my wildcard implementation?

Tags: java, wildcard

I have 3 classes(PriorityQueue, Assignment, AssignmentLog) and 1 Interface(IPriorityQueue).

```
public interface IPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
void add(T newEntry);
T remove();
T peek();
boolean isEmpty();
int getSize();
void clear(); }
```

PriorityQueue class:

```
public class PriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements IPriorityQueue<T> {

private T[] priorityQueue;
private int frontIndex = 0;
private int backIndex = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE= 50;...
}
```

Assignment.java:

```
public class Assignment implements Comparable<Assignment> {
private String course;
private String task;
private Date dueDate;
@Override
public int compareTo(Assignment other) {
    return -dueDate.compareTo(other.dueDate);
}}
```

AssignmentLog.java:

```
public class AssignmentLog {
private IPriorityQueue<Assignment> log;

public AssignmentLog(){
    log = new PriorityQueue<>();
}

public void addProject(Assignment newAssignment){
    log.add(newAssignment);
}

public Assignment getProject(){
    return log.peek();
}
```

My question is even though the IDE does not recognize any error, when I run the program it shows an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Comparable; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Comparable; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:13)
    at PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:9)
    at AssignmentLog.<init>(AssignmentLog.java:5)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

line 13:`public PriorityQueue(int size){
        priorityQueue = (T[])new Object[size];
    }`
line 10: `public PriorityQueue(){
        this(DEFAULT_SIZE);
    }`

line 5: `public AssignmentLog(){
        log = new PriorityQueue<>();
    }`
line 13: `AssignmentLog myHomework = new AssignmentLog();`

Please explain me what is wrong with my assignment. I'm still really new to wild card, so please give me some advice

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the code where the exception is actually thrown?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem hello, I just edited. Thanks for your concern

Comment: You still haven't shown the code where the exception is thrown. That stack trace tells you it's line 13 of PriorityQueue.java.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Hello Kareem again, I just made correction again. If I still made mistakes please let me know

Comment: You cannot directly cast any `Object` to any arbitrary class.

Answer (score 3):

You're down-casting an `Object[]` to `T[]`. Down casting in Java to a class which is not a subclass throws an instance of `ClassCastException`.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) for `ClassCastException`:

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:
>
> ```java
> Object x = new Integer(0);
> System.out.println((String)x);
> ```

In the line `priorityQueue = (T[])new Object[size];`, when you try to cast the `Object[]` to `T[]`, Java does a type check. Since `Object` does not extend `T`, the cast fails. However, you must remember that each class other than `Object` implicitly extends `Object`.

If you're looking to initialize an object of type `T` inside a generic function, take a look at [Instantiating a generic class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java).