# How to inherit Generic types

Tags: java, generics

I have two packages and both packages have Excel classes and also Invoices and Packing classes, I would like to create one Excel where i could extend from ,each excel need to know about Invoice and Packing Lists

```
public class Excel {

   protected final List<? extends T> invoices;
   protected final List<? extends T> packing;

   public Excel(List<? extends T> invoices, List<? extends T> packing) {
      this.invoices = invoices;
      this.packing = packing;
   }
}
```

I have extended that Excel in another Excel class and in the constructor `super(invoices,packing)` it says required type List ? extends T provided List Invoices List Packing

```
public Excel(List<Invoice> invoices, List<PackingList> packingLists) {
    super(invoices,packingLists);
```

Comment: Is `T` a generic type parameter? If it is, where is it declared?

Comment: @Eran i have created fields thinking that List could taky anything he like and then when extending that class just passing that lists of specific classes

Comment: What is `T`? If it's a generic type parameter, it should be declared either in the class level or in any relevant method. If it's not, this means you must have some class or interface named `T`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instantiating a generic class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by addin  on top of your class

```
 public class Excel <T>{

   protected final List<? extends T> invoices;
   protected final List<? extends T> packing;

   public Excel(List<? extends T> invoices, List<? extends T> packing) {
      this.invoices = invoices;
      this.packing = packing;
   }
}
```

and now when you want to call it you can just extend it like this

```
public class Something extends Excel <YourClass>
```

Answer (score 1):

As **Eran** pointed out. If you want to use generic parameters you need to **declare** them somewhere. Here you don't declare `T` so you **cannot** use it.

With the following code :

```java
public class Excel<T> {

// ...

}
```

When you create a new Excel you will be able to specify the type you want :

```java
Excel<MyType> excel = new Excel<>();
```

You could also implement a generic interface.