# Initialize a bounded generic type Java

Tags: java, generics, initialization, supplier

I am looking for alternatives to initialize a bounded generic type in Java. So far I have found 3 potential alternatives:

1. Generics [Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java#:%7E:text=Simple%20answer%20is%20%22you%20cant,constructor%20of%20Foo%20.)
2. Storing a [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java#:%7E:text=Simple%20answer%20is%20%22you%20cant,constructor%20of%20Foo%20.)
3. Built in Supplier [interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java/36315051#36315051)

Initially, I thought that the generics factory would be more flexible, however as I saw the built-in supplier, I believe that this would be flexible and also easier to maintain. So I created the following example based on [SomeContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java/36315051#36315051):
[image: Car Example]

Given that I have a CarPart class that has a subclass, and I have a car class (where T extends CarPart) that should hold a list of any type that extends the class CarPart.
I am trying to see if there is an alternative to initialize any potential CarPart subclass and add to the carParts list (method addNewGenericCarPart()).

Here is the code:

```java
public class Car<T extends CarPart> {
    private Supplier<T> carPartsSupplier;
    List<T> carParts;

    Car(Supplier<T> carPartsSupplier){
        this.carPartsSupplier=carPartsSupplier;
    }

    T createCarParts(){
        return carPartsSupplier.get();
    }

    public Car(List<T> carParts) {
        this.carParts = carParts;
    }
    void addNewGenericCarPart(){
//        TODO:Create a new generic Part Subclass
        Car<T> anythingExtendsCarParts=
                new T(T::new);//Error:Cannot resolve constructor 'T'

//        TODO:Add the new generic Part to carParts
        carParts.add(anythingExtendsCarParts);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CarPart {
    String name="default";

    public CarPart() {
    }

    public CarPart(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void printCarParts(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CarPartSubclass extends CarPart {
    String subname;

    public CarPartSubclass() {
    }

    public CarPartSubclass(String name, String subname) {
        super(name);
        this.subname = subname;
    }

    void print(){
        System.out.println("This is a CarpartSubclass");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] string) {
        List<CarPartSubclass> carPartsSubclassList=new ArrayList<>();
        carPartsSubclassList.add(new CarPartSubclass());

        Car<CarPartSubclass> car=new Car<CarPartSubclass>(carPartsSubclassList);
        car.addNewGenericCarPart();
    }
}
```

The above code results in the error

> Cannot resolve constructor 'T' in the method addNewGenericCarPart() in
> the class Car.

- Does anyone know if it is possible to create a workaround?
- Or is there any alternative to be able to initialize a generic bounded class?

Comment: Yeah, `new T(T::new)` T has no type here, generics are erased at runtime.  You'll need an actual class there in order to instantiate it.

Comment: Can't you use your `carPartsSupplier`? This is already a factory for car parts ...